# How do I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, is-empty

Is there a `string.Empty` in JavaScript, or is it just a case of checking for `""`?

Comment: just FYI, i think the most useful APIs for the String class are at [Mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:String) and [javascript kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string4.shtml). [elated.com](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-strings/ ) has a tutorial on all of String's properties, methods,... Please note: the Mozilla link has been updated to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491147/7026966

Comment: It would help greatly if the requirement was clearly specified. For what values should *isEmpty* return true? Checking for "" infers that it should only return true if the value is Type string and length 0. Many answers here assume it should also return true for some or all falsey values.

Comment: str.length > -1

Comment: I completely agree with @RobG, this question is badly defined. Why on earth would you consider `null` or `undefined` empty? An empty string is an empty string, it is not `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Also, an empty string cannot contain whitespace, like a lot of answers are assuming!

Comment: @GeneT's link is broken, so here's an updated link to Mozilla's reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 4953, accepted):

#### Empty string, undefined, null, ...

To check for a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```
if (strValue) {
    // strValue was non-empty string, true, 42, Infinity, [], ...
}
```

To check for a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

```
if (!strValue) {
    // strValue was empty string, false, 0, null, undefined, ...
}
```

---

#### Empty string (only!)

To check for exactly an empty string, compare for strict equality against `""` using the [`===` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality):

```
if (strValue === "") {
    // strValue was empty string
}
```

To check for not an empty string strictly, use the [`!==` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality):

```
if (strValue !== "") {
    // strValue was not an empty string
}
```

Comment: Testing the length property may actually be faster than testing the string against "", because the interpreter won't have to create a String object from the string literal.

Comment: @Vincent doing some naïve profiling in Chrome developer tools, testing `=== ''` vs `.length` didn't show any discernible improvement (and using `.length` only works if you can assume that you have a string)

Comment: @bdukes when you start to care about that kind of micro-optimizations, I don't think Chrome is the browser where you are having most of your performance problems...

Comment: Just to note, if your definition of "empty string" includes whitespace, then this solution is not appropriate. A string of 1 or more spaces returns true above. If you are using JQuery you can simply use this: if ($.trim(ref).length === 0) - as per this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031085/how-can-i-check-if-string-contains-characters-whitespace-not-just-whitespace/6610847#6610847

Comment: As expected `.length > 0` is actually **much faster** than comparing to a string literal! Check out this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/vs-length-0)

Comment: @Chad, Your jsPerf is quite flawed, as one of the tests compares for a specific value, whereas the other compares for any value except empty. So to make it fair the first test should be `s!==""` which is 'only' 24% slower than `s.length > 0`

Comment: Since it varies from each version of Chrome the proper way is to write it so that it identifies which version of chrome is in which list and uses the fastest method :P You'll spend more cycles checking out which version of chrome you're running and which is the fastest. Honestly it's so close in comparison lately just pick whatever flavor suits you best. Not checking the length is nice for some duck-type-ability. Although everyone knows the dangers of ducks and should be running TypeScript; fact™.

Comment: str=0;   if(str) retun false

Comment: what if we need to pass this check as lamda? f.e:                                    
  if (users.some(u => u.GroupRole)){} In this case there's complilation error telling me to pass bool not string

Comment: @kir.gera, JavaScript doesn't give compilation errors, are you getting this error from the TypeScript compiler?  If your compiler wants a strict `bool` value, you could to `Boolean(u.GroupRole)` or `!!u.GroupRole`

Comment: @casademora This is not Good answer because in some situation at start create page initializing by `null` and this `strValue === ""` not work.
the best syntax is `!strValue` GoodLuck

Comment: Before your focus going to performance difference, think about how many times will it be run. For example the "if" statement runned once per site, your performance optimalisation is near zero. and if your code is longer than original, mybe you loose more time on network than won on javascript execution. And at last, when you use any build tool, then these microoptimalization will be lost. So my advice is "write more readable code"

Comment: Surprised not to see any mention of "falsy values" here...

Answer (score 1425):

For checking if a variable is [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) or if it has length attribute equal to zero (which for a string, means it is empty), I use:

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || str.length === 0 );
}
```

<sub>(Note that strings aren't the only variables with a `length` attribute, arrays have them as well, for example.)</sub>

Alternativaly, you can use the (not so) newly optional chaining and arrow functions to simplify:

```
const isEmpty = (str) => (!str?.length);
```

It will check the length, returning `undefined` in case of a nullish value, without throwing an error. In the case of an empty value, zero is falsy and the result is still valid.

For checking if a variable is falsey or if the string only contains whitespace or is empty, I use:

```
function isBlank(str) {
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
```

If you want, you can [monkey-patch](https://www.audero.it/blog/2016/12/05/monkey-patching-javascript/) the `String` prototype like this:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    // This doesn't work the same way as the isEmpty function used 
    // in the first example, it will return true for strings containing only whitespace
    return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
};
console.log("example".isEmpty());
```

<sub>Note that monkey-patching built-in types are controversial, as it can break code that depends on the existing structure of built-in types, for whatever reason.</sub>

Comment: why 0 === str.length instead of str.length === 0 ?

Comment: @Vincent Conditions are often written like this `if (variable == constant value)` and if you forget an '=' then you're assigning the constant value to the variable instead of testing. The code will still work as you can assign variable in a if. So a safer way to write this condition is to reverse the constant value and the variable. This way when you test your code you'll see an error (Invalid lef-hand side in assignment). You can also use something like JSHint to disallow assignment in conditions and be warned when you write one.

Comment: I forgot to mention that as you mostly use '===' or '!==' you are less exposed to that kind of mistake.

Comment: shame that `/^\s*$/.test(str)` is not really readable - maybe removing spaces using simpler code or regex would be better? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: I like that, and I added this to the String prototype String.prototype.isEmpty = function () {
    return (!this || 0 === this.length);
};

Comment: /^\s*$/.test(str) can be replaced with str.trim().length === 0

Comment: @Vincent this is also called "Yoda Conditions", like `if blue is the sky`.  See http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

Comment: How is `return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim())` any better than just `return !this.trim()`?

Comment: It isn't really a good idea to be extending native prototypes though, it is generally considered a bad practice that a lot of people just recommend against doing so entirely as there are safer ways that are just as good. There is a SO discussion on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice), but every JS programming book I've read has strongly recommended against it. For OPs problem I usually just do `if (!str) { // i am sure str is empty null or undefined here if I'm sure it won't be another data type }`

Comment: Empty strings are falsey, so there's the second part of the condition isn't really needed: `(! str || str.length == 0)`

Comment: This is the best answer and handles every scenario I can test against it! (the isBlank() one)

Comment: @Jano Why the need for checking length here: `return (!str || str.length === 0 )`?

Comment: @ruffin Arrays. `console.log([] ? "true" : "false")` prints "true".

Comment: @JustinC Truthy, no doubt no doubt. I'm not sure what I was thinking before -- I would say I was only worried about strings. That is, in TypeScript, if `str` is of type `string`, you would not need the `.length` check. But I also said, "_another object type with `.length`_", which I assume meant I was thinking of non-strings (which makes sense in dynamic-JavaScript-land), in which case arrays are the obvious answer. So who knows what I was thinking. But now I'm thinking I'll just delete that comment.  Though an empty array _is not falsy_ -- what are we trying to check for again? 

Answer (score 559):

All the previous answers are good, but this will be even better. Use dual NOT operators (`!!`):

```js
if (!!str) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Or use type casting:

```js
if (Boolean(str)) {
    // Code here
}
```

Both do the same function. Typecast the variable to Boolean, where `str` is a variable.

- It returns `false` for `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `000`, `""`, `false`.
- It returns `true` for all string values other than the empty string (including strings like `"0"` and `" "`)

Comment: Is there any difference between the behavior of `if(str)` and `if(!!str)`?

Comment: @PeterOlson if you are trying to save a variable as a boolean that checks multiple strings for content then you would want to do this.. aka `var any = (!!str1 && !!str2 && !!str3)` handling if there is a number in there as well

Comment: This is the solution I always use. `!!str.trim()` to make sure the string is not made of whitespaces only.

Comment: Not not looks like a hack, `Boolean(str)` is a lot more readable and less "wtfish".

Comment: Note that `!!` is not an operator. It is one operator applied twice.

Comment: @JohnRuddell aren't the bangs redundant in `var any = (!!str1 && !!str2 && !!str3)`? Won't the `&&` operator convert the operands to booleans anyway?

Comment: @arth you can do that, it depends on your code style. When I do a Boolean check I like to cast to a bool via `!!` so you ensure consistent behavior... when you aren't dealing with Boolean values, a browsers implementation could potentially behave differently

Comment: @JohnRuddell Why would a browser's implicit conversion of a variable to a Boolean vary between the ! operator and the && operator? .. and if it would, why trust one and not the other?

Comment: @Arth @JohnRuddell: no, the bangs aren't redundant. For example, `'aa' && 'ddd'` returns `'ddd'`, not `true`. `'ddd'` happens to further evaluate as `true`, which is why you can use just `'aa' && 'ddd'` as-is in an `if` statement. But if you're assigning the result to a boolean the bangs are needed.

Comment: @JohnRuddell @Arth: in other words, javascript's `&&` does not return a boolean unless the operand it picks happens to be a boolean. Here's the definition of its behavior (for `expr1 && expr2`): "If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr2; else, returns expr1".

Comment: @AlvinThompson Ah yes, I missed that.. thanks, good point! When assigning a boolean var, explicit conversion is necessary, but could be done as `!!(str1 && str2 && str3)` or `Boolean(str1 && str2 && str3)` instead. When not assigning, an explicit conversion is superfluous, `if (str1 && str2 && str3){}`is enough..

Comment: This is simply useless in a `if`, it converts falsy values to `false` and truthy values to `true`. A `if` block either executes or not based on wether the expression is truthy, there is no point adding `!!`

Comment: For those wondering: 1. `Boolean(expr)` is just the same as `!!expr` 2. `Boolean(expr)` inside an if is sort of useless; if already implicitly casts the expression given inside it. This might come as a surprise to those coming from C# for example.

Comment: This doesnt work with string whitespace. Adding Darias suggestion doesnt work on nulls.

Comment: Unless you're interfacing with a JavaScript-hostile third party library (including JSX!), no, please leave off the `!!` -- [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29951409/1028230). JavaScript a dynamic language, and it'll pay off for you in the long run to think like the language, not coerce the language to think like you. What this answer is really telling us is that `if (str) { /* go */ } else { /* don't go */ }` is all the check you need.

Answer (score 134):

The closest thing you can get to `str.Empty` (with the precondition that str is a String) is:

```
if (!str.length) { ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't that throw an exception is str is null?

Comment: @PicMickael Yes! So would `str.Empty`.

Comment: Note that strings aren't the only type of variable that have a `length` attribute. Arrays do as well.

Answer (score 116):

If you need to make sure that the string is not just a bunch of empty spaces (I'm assuming this is for form validation) you need to do a replace on the spaces.

```
if(str.replace(/\s/g,"") == ""){
}
```

Comment: But does the job if what you actually want to test for is a string with non-space content. Is there a less-expensive way to test this?

Comment: How about the length property?

Comment: Instead of removing all the spaces, why not just check if there's a non-space? Has 2 advantages that it can bail out early if there is a non-space character, and it doesn't have return a new string which you then check against. `if(str.match(/\S/g)){}`

Comment: @Mark FYI, you wouldn't need the global modifier, since the match of the first occurrence of a non-space character would mean the string is not empty: `str.match(/\S/)`

Comment: why it is expensive? If truly is, then why jQuery uses this method? You can find this in jQuery's source `var trimLeft = /^\s+/, trimRight = /\s+$/;`

Comment: +1 I tried this method and it worked for me. The user may enter blank spaces which is still blank.

Comment: `if(str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")){...}+` would be enough

Comment: Perhaps `/\S/.test(str)` is better than `str.match(/\S/)` because it doesn't bother with returning an array of matched results (might be micro performance gain there). Also, when just *testing* a string against a regexp, use the RegExp `.test()` method to better convey that intent.

Answer (score 78):

I use:

```js
function empty(e) {
  switch (e) {
    case "":
    case 0:
    case "0":
    case null:
    case false:
    case undefined:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

empty(null) // true
empty(0) // true
empty(7) // false
empty("") // true
empty((function() {
    return ""
})) // false
```

Comment: This solution is more language agnostic. The only JavaScript feature it relies on is typeof. So it is a good example of a solution you can use when you don't trust the implementations in different browsers and don't have time to grab a better solution. (IE, no internet access). It's something like a proof. Not the cleanest but you can be sure it will work without knowing too much about JavaScript.

Comment: I'd go even a bit further, and nail it with a === operator for the undefined case. Otherwise it's just simply the perfect answer.

Comment: The `typeof` in the `switch` did not work for me. I added a `if (typeof e == "undefined")` test and that works. Why?

Comment: @Lucas Because this was a typo or an oversight.  Your modification is the correct approach. (the original refers to the context of the empty function, not the e parameter, which is what the function is supposed to check)

Comment: Could we use ``case undefined:`` instead of ``case typeof(e) == "undefined":``?

Comment: `case typeof(e) == "undefined":` is wrong; that matches an `e` of `false`, not of `undefined`. Apparently this was a [suggested edit](/review/suggested-edits/25444037) which got approved. The original `case typeof this == "undefined":` still doesn’t make any sense. There’s also no reason to consider `false`, `0`, and `"0"` “empty”.

Comment: Just goes to show how ludicrous this beautiful language is :(

Comment: This function returns true for `isEmpty("0")`, which to me is surprising and unwanted behaviour. In Javascript, `"0"` is evaluated to true in boolean contexts, and so I would not expect it to be considered empty.

Comment: @BorisJ. yes, using `case undefined:` would be a correct fix for this bug. (I edited the answer to use this instead).

Comment: This solution is as bad as loose equality (with how it treats `'0'` as "empty"), and it's incomplete (it won't check if a set, map, or user-defined class is empty if those got passed in), and it really doesn't make much sense (Why are we checking for emptiness on numbers and booleans? Those aren't containers). And, it's unnecessary - you should know what data type you're dealing with, and be able to do the appropriate emptiness check for it on-the-spot. This will be much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 73):

### Performance

I perform tests on [macOS v10.13.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) for 18 chosen solutions. Solutions works slightly different (for corner-case input data) which was presented in the snippet below.

**Conclusions**

- the simple solutions based on `!str`,`==`,`===` and `length` are fast for all browsers (A,B,C,G,I,J)
- the solutions based on the regular expression (`test`,`replace`) and `charAt` are slowest for all browsers (H,L,M,P)
- the solutions marked as fastest was fastest only for one test run - but in many runs it changes inside 'fast' solutions group

[image]

### Details

In the below snippet I compare results of chosen 18 methods by use different input parameters

- `""` `"a"` `" "`- empty string, string with letter and string with space
- `[]` `{}` `f`- array, object and function
- `0` `1` `NaN` `Infinity` - numbers
- `true` `false` - Boolean
- `null` `undefined`

Not all tested methods support all input cases.

```js
function A(str) {
  let r=1;
  if (!str)
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function B(str) {
  let r=1;
  if (str == "")
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function C(str) {
  let r=1;
  if (str === "")
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function D(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str || 0 === str.length)
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function E(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str || /^\s*$/.test(str))
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function F(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!Boolean(str))
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function G(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(! ((typeof str != 'undefined') && str) )
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function H(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!/\S/.test(str))
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function I(str) {
  let r=1;
  if (!str.length)
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function J(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(str.length <= 0)
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function K(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(str.length === 0 || !str.trim())
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function L(str) {
  let r=1;
  if ( str.replace(/\s/g,"") == "")
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function M(str) {
  let r=1;
  if((/^\s*$/).test(str))
    r=0;
  return r;
}


function N(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str || !str.trim().length)
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function O(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str || !str.trim())
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function P(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str.charAt(0))
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function Q(str) {
  let r=1;
  if(!str || (str.trim()==''))
    r=0;
  return r;
}

function R(str) {
  let r=1;
  if (typeof str == 'undefined' ||
      !str ||
      str.length === 0 ||
      str === "" ||
      !/[^\s]/.test(str) ||
      /^\s*$/.test(str) ||
      str.replace(/\s/g,"") === "")

    r=0;
  return r;
}




// --- TEST ---

console.log(                  '   ""  "a"  " " [] {} 0 1 NaN Infinity f true false null undefined ');
let log1 = (s,f)=> console.log(`${s}: ${f("")}   ${f("a")}    ${f(" ")}   ${f([])}  ${f({})}  ${f(0)} ${f(1)} ${f(NaN)}   ${f(Infinity)}        ${f(f)} ${f(true)}    ${f(false)}     ${f(null)}    ${f(undefined)}`);
let log2 = (s,f)=> console.log(`${s}: ${f("")}   ${f("a")}    ${f(" ")}   ${f([])}  ${f({})}  ${f(0)} ${f(1)} ${f(NaN)}   ${f(Infinity)}        ${f(f)} ${f(true)}    ${f(false)}`);
let log3 = (s,f)=> console.log(`${s}: ${f("")}   ${f("a")}    ${f(" ")}`);

log1('A', A);
log1('B', B);
log1('C', C);
log1('D', D);
log1('E', E);
log1('F', F);
log1('G', G);
log1('H', H);

log2('I', I);
log2('J', J);

log3('K', K);
log3('L', L);
log3('M', M);
log3('N', N);
log3('O', O);
log3('P', P);
log3('Q', Q);
log3('R', R);
```

And then for all methods I perform speed test case `str = ""` for browsers Chrome v78.0.0, Safari v13.0.4, and Firefox v71.0.0 - you can run tests on your machine [here](https://jsperf.com/empty-string-checking/1)

[image]

Comment: Kind of misleading since it combines trim solutions with no-trim solutions.

Answer (score 61):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/):
_.isEmpty(value).

It covers a lot of cases like `{}`, `''`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.

But it always returns `true` for `Number` type of [JavaScript primitive data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) like `_.isEmpty(10)` or `_.isEmpty(Number.MAX_VALUE)` both returns `true`.

Comment: `_.isEmpty(" "); // => false`

Comment: @Erich Because `" "` is not empty. `_.isEmpty("");` returns true.

Comment: quite true - i mentioned this because a few of the other answers on here imply form validation and checking if a string consists of only whitespace, and this single lodash function by itself will not solve that problem.

Answer (score 43):

Very generic "All-In-One" Function (*not recommended though*):

```
function is_empty(x)
{
    return (                                                           //don't put newline after return
        (typeof x == 'undefined')
              ||
        (x == null)
              ||
        (x == false)        //same as: !x
              ||
        (x.length == 0)
              ||
        (x == 0)            // note this line, you might not need this. 
              ||
        (x == "")
              ||
        (x.replace(/\s/g,"") == "")
              ||
        (!/[^\s]/.test(x))
              ||
        (/^\s*$/.test(x))
    );
}
```

However, I don't recommend to use that, because your target variable should be of specific type (i.e. string, or numeric, or object?), so apply the checks that are relative to that variable.

Comment: Any chance you could explain what each check is doing? :)

Comment: -1 They are testing for different things. It makes no sense to put them all into one `if` statement.

Comment: typeof MyVariable == 'undefined' doesn't discern between an initialized variable with an undefined value and an undeclared variable unless the variable was initially declared and initialized to null. Checking the length property causes the string primitive to be wrapped in a string object.

Answer (score 42):

```
var s; // undefined
var s = ""; // ""
s.length // 0
```

There's nothing representing an empty string in JavaScript. Do a check against either `length` (if you know that the var will always be a string) or against `""`

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: `There's nothing representing an empty string in JavaScript. `. What about `""`, doesn't that represent an empty string?

Answer (score 41):

Try:

```
if (str && str.trim().length) {  
    //...
}
```

Comment: `str.trim().length` will do faster than `str.trim()`, by around 1% according to my own testing result.

Comment: OP is looking to test for empty string, undefined, or null. This is testing for a string that is not any of those conditions. He didn't say anything about whitespace only strings either. You can test for OP's conditions with just this, as long as you are sure no other data types are stored in the variable:  `if (!str) { ... }`

Answer (score 32):

I would not worry too much about the most **efficient** method. Use what is most clear to your intention. For me that's usually `strVar == ""`.

As per the comment from [Constantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20310/constantin), if strVar could some how end up containing an integer 0 value, then that would indeed be one of those intention-clarifying situations.

Comment: Bad idea. You'll get true if strVar is accidentally assigned 0.

Comment: I agree that making your intention clear is more important than any micro-optimizations other methods might yield, but using the [strict comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) `===` would be better. It only returns true if `strVar` is an empty string.

Comment: The check fails if undefined. So if(str) works better

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz if str were assigned a falsey value of 0 or "0", if(str) would falsely report true. The best approach is if(str === ""). It's simple and it will never fail.

Comment: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/86967)

Answer (score 25):

```
if ((input?.trim()?.length || 0) > 0) {
   // input must not be any of:
   // undefined
   // null
   // ""
   // " " or just whitespace
}
```

Or in function form:

```
const isNotNilOrWhitespace = input => (input?.trim()?.length || 0) > 0;

const isNilOrWhitespace = input => (input?.trim()?.length || 0) === 0;
```

Explanation:

If `input` is `undefined` or `null` then the null coalescing `?.` will result in `input?.trim()?.length` will be `undefined` or `null`. ORing (`||`) that with `0` will give `0`. `0` is not `> 0` therefore the result will be `false`, ie it IS a nil value.

If `input` is empty or whitespace then `.trim()` will remove leading and ending whitespace, which will keep an empty input the same, and convert any whitespace to an empty value. The length of an empty string is then `0`, and as above, `0` is not `> 0`, therefore the result will be `false`, ie it IS empty or only whitespace.

If `input` is any other string, it's length will be > 0 after calling `.trim()`, and therefore the result will be `true`, ie it IS NOT a nil value, and it IS NOT empty or only whitespace.

Comment: could you please give more explanation?

Comment: Explanation added

Comment: why so complicated? how about `const isNilOrWhitespace = input => !input?.trim();`

Answer (score 24):

There is a lot of useful information here, but in my opinion, one of the most important elements was not addressed.

`null`, `undefined`, and `""` are all *falsy*.

When evaluating an empty string, it's often because you need to replace it with something else.

In this case, you can expect the following behavior.

```
var a = ""
var b = null
var c = undefined

console.log(a || "falsy string provided") // prints ->"falsy string provided"
console.log(b || "falsy string provided") // prints ->"falsy string provided"
console.log(c || "falsy string provided") // prints ->"falsy string provided"
```

With that in mind, a method or function that can return whether or not a string is `""`, `null`, or `undefined` (an invalid string) versus a valid string is as simple as this:

```
const validStr = (str) => str ? true : false

validStr(undefined) // returns false
validStr(null) // returns false
validStr("") // returns false
validStr("My String") // returns true
```

Please note, you probably also want to `trim()` the string since `"" !== " "`.

Comment: thank you, i like your anwser, it is so simple. So just use: if (str) { //some code }                              when str is not null && not undefined && not empty string, then the if condition is true

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You will probably, however, want to ensure that there's not empty white space. Because:

```js
const emptStr = ""
```
Is not the same as 
```js
const notEmptyStr = "      "
```

And the latter is not falsy.

Answer (score 22):

A lot of answers, and a lot of different possibilities!

Without a doubt for quick and simple implementation the winner is: `if (!str.length) {...}`

However, as many other examples are available. The best functional method to go about this, I would suggest:

```js
function empty(str)
{
    if (typeof str == 'undefined' || !str || str.length === 0 || str === "" || !/[^\s]/.test(str) || /^\s*$/.test(str) || str.replace(/\s/g,"") === "")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

A bit excessive, I know.

Comment: Checking for undefined would need to be moved to first in the checks, or undefined items will throw exceptions on the earlier checks.

Comment: Completely agree! NICE CATCH. I will edit my above answer!

Comment: `str.length === 0` returns true for any function that has no formal parameters.

Comment: str.length === 0 || str === "" both would do the same task.

Answer (score 21):

You could also go with regular expressions:

```
if((/^\s*$/).test(str)) { }
```

Checks for strings that are either empty or filled with whitespace.

Comment: It works, but it's also horribly expensive ops-wise. Good if you just want to check one or two things, not a large set.

Answer (score 21):

1. check that `var a;` exist
2. trim out the false spaces in the value, then test for emptiness

   ```
    if ((a)&&(a.trim()!=''))
    {
      // if variable a is not empty do this 
    }
   ```

Comment: The string `"  "` is not empty, but it would be considered empty by this condition.

Answer (score 20):

I usually use something like this,

```
if (!str.length) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Fastest if you know that the variable is a string. Throws an error if the variable is undefined.

Comment: @AdrianHope-Bailie why would you test an undefined variable?

Comment: @AbimaelMartell Why not? You have a variable that either you declared or that was passed to you from some scope you have no control over such as in a response from a method or API call. You can assume it contains a value and use the check above but if it is not defined or is null you will get an error.
var test = null; if(!test.length){alert("adrian is wrong");}

Comment: OP was asking for "how to check for an empty string", un undefined variable is not an empty string. Anyway you could check `typeof variable != "undefined"` before checking if is empty.

Answer (score 18):

Also, in case you consider a whitespace filled string as "empty".

You can test it with this regular expression:

```
!/\S/.test(string); // Returns true if blank.
```

Answer (score 16):

If one needs to detect not only empty but also blank strings, I'll add to Goral's answer:

```
function isEmpty(s){
    return !s.length;    
}

function isBlank(s){
    return isEmpty(s.trim());    
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I use a combination, and the fastest checks are first.

```
function isBlank(pString) {
    if (!pString) {
        return true;
    }
    // Checks for a non-white space character
    // which I think [citation needed] is faster
    // than removing all the whitespace and checking
    // against an empty string
    return !/[^\s]+/.test(pString);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if you could explain when the length check would be necessary? Wouldn't !pString catch anything that was null/empty string? This seems to work. var test=''; if (!test) alert('empty');

Comment: I didn't see this comment until a decade later.  But yes, you're right, I'll update. :)

Comment: Combining our knowledge 1 decade at a time :)

Comment: @Nicholi see you in 2031!

Answer (score 14):

Starting with:

```
return (!value || value == undefined || value == "" || value.length == 0);
```

Looking at the last condition, if value == "", its length *must* be 0. Therefore drop it:

```
return (!value || value == undefined || value == "");
```

But wait! In JavaScript, an empty string is false. Therefore, drop value == "":

```
return (!value || value == undefined);
```

And !undefined is true, so that check isn't needed. So we have:

```
return (!value);
```

And we don't need parentheses:

```
return !value
```

Comment: what happens if `value = false` or `value = 0`. will you return the correct response according to the question?

Answer (score 13):

I have not noticed an answer that takes into account the possibility of null characters in a string. For example, if we have a null character string:

```
var y = "\0"; // an empty string, but has a null character
(y === "") // false, testing against an empty string does not work
(y.length === 0) // false
(y) // true, this is also not expected
(y.match(/^[\s]*$/)) // false, again not wanted
```

To test its nullness one could do something like this:

```
String.prototype.isNull = function(){ 
  return Boolean(this.match(/^[\0]*$/)); 
}
...
"\0".isNull() // true
```

It works on a null string, and on an empty string and it is accessible for all strings. In addition, it could be expanded to contain other JavaScript empty or whitespace characters (i.e. nonbreaking space, byte order mark, line/paragraph separator, etc.).

Comment: Interesting analysis. I don't think this would be relevant in 99.9% of cases. BUT I recently found that MySQL evaluates a column to "null" if (and only if) that column contains the null character ("\0"). Oracle on the other hand would not evaluate "\0" as being null, preferring to treat it as a string of length 1 (where that one character is the null character). This could cause confusion if not dealt with properly, because many web-developers do work with a back-end database, which might pass through different types of "null" values. It should be at the back of every developer's mind.

Answer (score 11):

I did some research on what happens if you pass a non-string and non-empty/null value to a tester function. As many know, (0 == "") is true in JavaScript, but since 0 is a value and not empty or null, you may want to test for it.

The following two functions return true only for undefined, null, empty/whitespace values and false for everything else, such as numbers, Boolean, objects, expressions, etc.

```
function IsNullOrEmpty(value)
{
    return (value == null || value === "");
}
function IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
{
    return (value == null || !/\S/.test(value));
}
```

More complicated examples exists, but these are simple and give consistent results. There is no need to test for undefined, since it's included in (value == null) check. You may also mimic [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) behaviour by adding them to String like this:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty = function (value) { ... }
```

You do not want to put it in Strings prototype, because if the instance of the String-class is null, it will error:

```
String.prototype.IsNullOrEmpty = function (value) { ... }
var myvar = null;
if (1 == 2) { myvar = "OK"; } // Could be set
myvar.IsNullOrEmpty(); // Throws error
```

I tested with the following value array. You can loop it through to test your functions if in doubt.

```
// Helper items
var MyClass = function (b) { this.a = "Hello World!"; this.b = b; };
MyClass.prototype.hello = function () { if (this.b == null) { alert(this.a); } else { alert(this.b); } };
var z;
var arr = [
// 0: Explanation for printing, 1: actual value
    ['undefined', undefined],
    ['(var) z', z],
    ['null', null],
    ['empty', ''],
    ['space', ' '],
    ['tab', '\t'],
    ['newline', '\n'],
    ['carriage return', '\r'],
    ['"\\r\\n"', '\r\n'],
    ['"\\n\\r"', '\n\r'],
    ['" \\t \\n "', ' \t \n '],
    ['" txt \\t test \\n"', ' txt \t test \n'],
    ['"txt"', "txt"],
    ['"undefined"', 'undefined'],
    ['"null"', 'null'],
    ['"0"', '0'],
    ['"1"', '1'],
    ['"1.5"', '1.5'],
    ['"1,5"', '1,5'], // Valid number in some locales, not in JavaScript
    ['comma', ','],
    ['dot', '.'],
    ['".5"', '.5'],
    ['0', 0],
    ['0.0', 0.0],
    ['1', 1],
    ['1.5', 1.5],
    ['NaN', NaN],
    ['/\S/', /\S/],
    ['true', true],
    ['false', false],
    ['function, returns true', function () { return true; } ],
    ['function, returns false', function () { return false; } ],
    ['function, returns null', function () { return null; } ],
    ['function, returns string', function () { return "test"; } ],
    ['function, returns undefined', function () { } ],
    ['MyClass', MyClass],
    ['new MyClass', new MyClass()],
    ['empty object', {}],
    ['non-empty object', { a: "a", match: "bogus", test: "bogus"}],
    ['object with toString: string', { a: "a", match: "bogus", test: "bogus", toString: function () { return "test"; } }],
    ['object with toString: null', { a: "a", match: "bogus", test: "bogus", toString: function () { return null; } }]
];
```

Comment: If you simply stop using == and use ===, then this solves the problem if(s === "").

Answer (score 11):

Meanwhile we can have one function that checks for all 'empties' like **null, undefined, '', ' ', {}, []**.
So I just wrote this.

```
var isEmpty = function(data) {
    if(typeof(data) === 'object'){
        if(JSON.stringify(data) === '{}' || JSON.stringify(data) === '[]'){
            return true;
        }else if(!data){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }else if(typeof(data) === 'string'){
        if(!data.trim()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }else if(typeof(data) === 'undefined'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use cases and results.

```
console.log(isEmpty()); // true
console.log(isEmpty(null)); // true
console.log(isEmpty('')); // true
console.log(isEmpty('  ')); // true
console.log(isEmpty(undefined)); // true
console.log(isEmpty({})); // true
console.log(isEmpty([])); // true
console.log(isEmpty(0)); // false
console.log(isEmpty('Hey')); // false
```

Answer (score 11):

I didn't see a good answer here (at least not an answer that fits for me)

So I decided to answer myself:

`value === undefined || value === null || value === "";`

You need to start checking if it's undefined. Otherwise your method can explode, and then you can check if it equals null or is equal to an empty string.

You cannot have !! or only `if(value)` since if you check `0` it's going to give you a false answer (0 is false).

With that said, wrap it up in a method like:

`public static isEmpty(value: any): boolean {
    return value === undefined || value === null || value === "";
}`

PS.: **You don't need to check typeof**, since it would explode and throw even before it enters the method

Comment: Probably better use Boolean(value) construct that treats undefined and null values (and also 0, -0, false, NaN) as false. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript

Answer (score 10):

All these answers are nice.

But I cannot be sure that variable is a string, doesn't contain only spaces (this is important for me), and can contain '0' (string).

My version:

```
function empty(str){
    return !str || !/[^\s]+/.test(str);
}

empty(null); // true
empty(0); // true
empty(7); // false
empty(""); // true
empty("0"); // false
empty("  "); // true
```

Sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZfGs/).

Comment: Huh? If you are expecting a string, `empty(0)` and `empty(7)` should return the same value.

Comment: In my particular case - `empty("0")` must return `false` (because that is a not empty string), but `empty(0)` must return `true` because it is empty :)

Comment: But 0 *isn't* empty! It's a number, and numbers can't be full or empty. Of course, it's your function and so must satisfy your requirements, but `empty` is a misleading name in this case.

Comment: I think that name `empty` is good. In php docs for [empty](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function: `Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.` The difference between `PHP` and this function - that string `'0'` will be not identified as empty.

Comment: As I say, it's your function: call it what you want. But `empty` is an inaccurate and misleading name. It's interesting that PHP also has a poorly-named `empty` function, but PHP's failings don't have anything to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
export const isEmpty = string => (!string || !string.length);
```

Answer (score 10):

Trimming whitespace with the null-coalescing operator:

```js
if (!str?.trim()) {
  // do something...
}
```

Comment: It looks cool but str.trim() is sufficient. One should never overcomplicate things IMO.

Comment: Just throwing it out for those people who might need it. `?.` couldn't be less complicated. `.trim()` would throw an error if `str` is nullish.

Answer (score 9):

Ignoring whitespace strings, you could use this to check for null, empty and undefined:

```
var obj = {};
(!!obj.str) // Returns false

obj.str = "";
(!!obj.str) // Returns false

obj.str = null;
(!!obj.str) // Returns false
```

It is concise and it works for undefined properties, although it's not the most readable.

Comment: You are checking for truthiness, here, which is bit more complicated than merely checking for empty strings, `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 9):

There's no `isEmpty()` method, you have to check for the type and the length:

```
if (typeof test === 'string' && test.length === 0){
  ...
```

The type check is needed in order to avoid runtime errors when `test` is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `test === ""` is equivalent, and it's shorter.

Answer (score 7):

I usually use something like:

```
if (str == "") {
     //Do Something
}
else {
     //Do Something Else
}
```

Comment: `==` operator is not strict. So if `str == ""`, `str` can be `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `[]`, etc..

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
str.value.length == 0
```

Comment: `"".value.length` will cause an error. It should be `str.length === 0`

Comment: This trow a `TypeError` If `str` is equal to `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 7):

You can easily add it to native **String** object in **JavaScript** and reuse it over and over...
Something simple like below code can do the job for you if you want to check `''` empty strings:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = String.prototype.isEmpty || function() {
  return !(!!this.length);
}
```

Otherwise if you'd like to check both `''` empty string and `'   '` with space, you can do that by just adding `trim()`, something like the code below:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = String.prototype.isEmpty || function() {
   return !(!!this.trim().length);
}
```

and you can call it this way:

```
''.isEmpty(); //return true
'alireza'.isEmpty(); //return false
```

Comment: What benefit is there to doing `!(!!this.length)` rather than just `!this` (or `!this.trim()` for the second option)? A zero-length string is falsy already, the parentheses are redundant, and negating it three times is exactly the same as negating it once.

Comment: Please don't pollute prototypes.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practise to use monkey-patching like this.

Answer (score 6):

Don't assume that the variable you check is a string. Don't assume that if this var has a length, then it's a string.

The thing is: think carefully about what your app must do and can accept. Build something robust.

If your method / function should only process a non empty string then test if the argument is a non empty string and don't do some 'trick'.

As an example of something that will explode if you follow some advices here not carefully.

```
var getLastChar = function (str) {
 if (str.length > 0)
   return str.charAt(str.length - 1)
}

getLastChar('hello')
=> "o"

getLastChar([0,1,2,3])
=> TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'charAt'
```

So, I'd stick with

```
if (myVar === '')
  ...
```

Comment: This answer should be pinned to the top.

Answer (score 6):

Check if it's type string AND if it's not empty:

```js
const isNonEmptyString = (val) => typeof val === 'string' && !!val
```

Answer (score 5):

You should always check for the type too, since JavaScript is a duck typed language, so you may not know when and how the data changed in the middle of the process. So, here's the better solution:

```js
    let undefinedStr;
    if (!undefinedStr) {
      console.log("String is undefined");
    }
    
    let emptyStr = "";
    if (!emptyStr) {
      console.log("String is empty");
    }
    
    let nullStr = null;
    if (!nullStr) {
      console.log("String is null");
    }
```

Comment: The first condition works for any falsey value, not just `undefined`. This answer is not checking for type.

Answer (score 5):

You can able to validate following ways and understand the difference.

```js
var j = undefined;
console.log((typeof j == 'undefined') ? "true":"false");
var j = null; 
console.log((j == null) ? "true":"false");
var j = "";
console.log((!j) ? "true":"false");
var j = "Hi";
console.log((!j) ? "true":"false");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check this using the typeof operator along with the length method.

```
const isNonEmptyString = (value) => typeof(value) == 'string' && value.length > 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
function isEmpty(strValue)
{
    // Test whether strValue is empty
    if (!strValue || strValue.trim() === "" ||
        (strValue.trim()).length === 0) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(strValue.trim()).length === 0)` at the end of the condition? Isn't it redundant with `strValue.trim() === ""`?

Answer (score 4):

```
function tell()
{
    var pass = document.getElementById('pasword').value;
    var plen = pass.length;

    // Now you can check if your string is empty as like
    if(plen==0)
    {
        alert('empty');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('you entered something');
    }
}

<input type='text' id='pasword' />
```

This is also a generic way to check if field is empty.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use not blank test instead of blank

```
function isNotBlank(str) {
   return (str && /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
```

Comment: Putting negation into function names is a bad idea. You code itself is fine,but the function should be called something like hasValue().  Why? What happens when you see code like this: "if (!isNotBlank(str))"... It is not immediately clear what the intent is supposed to be. It may not seem relevant to you for this simple example, but adding negation to a function name is always a bad idea.

Comment: IsNotBlank is a standard function and very popular function in StringUtils  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: it also provides the IsBlank to avoid the double negatives. I believe function names should reflect the functionality they perform and it would be easier for developers to see understand when they see isBlank and IsNotBlank function in same class.

Answer (score 4):

The [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) JavaScript library, http://underscorejs.org/, provides a very useful `_.isEmpty()` function for checking for empty strings and other empty objects.

Reference: http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty

> **isEmpty**  `_.isEmpty(object)` 
>   Returns true if an enumerable object contains no values (no enumerable own-properties). For strings and array-like objects _.isEmpty checks if the length property is 0.
>
> `_.isEmpty([1, 2, 3]);` 
>    => false
>
> `_.isEmpty({});` 
>   => true

Other very useful Underscore.js functions include:

- http://underscorejs.org/#isNull  `_.isNull(object)`
- http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined
- `_.isUndefined(value)`
- http://underscorejs.org/#has `_.has(object, key)`

Answer (score 4):

The following regular expression is another solution, that can be used for null, empty or undefined string.

```
(/(null|undefined|^$)/).test(null)
```

I added this solution, because it can be extended further to check empty or some value like as follow. The following regular expression is checking either string can be empty null undefined or it has integers only.

```
(/(null|undefined|^$|^\d+$)/).test()
```

Comment: A major flaw: this regex matches the string literal "null". `(/(null|undefined|^$)/).test("null")`

Answer (score 4):

The **ultimate and shortest** variant of the *isBlank* function:

```js
/**
 * Will return:
 * False for: for all strings with chars
 * True for: false, null, undefined, 0, 0.0, "", " ".
 *
 * @param str
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isBlank(str){
    return (!!!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}

// tests
console.log("isBlank TRUE variants:");
console.log(isBlank(false));
console.log(isBlank(undefined));
console.log(isBlank(null));
console.log(isBlank(0));
console.log(isBlank(0.0));
console.log(isBlank(""));
console.log(isBlank(" "));

console.log("isBlank FALSE variants:");
console.log(isBlank("0"));
console.log(isBlank("0.0"));
console.log(isBlank(" 0"));
console.log(isBlank("0 "));
console.log(isBlank("Test string"));
console.log(isBlank("true"));
console.log(isBlank("false"));
console.log(isBlank("null"));
console.log(isBlank("undefined"));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a [*falsy* value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

The first solution:

```
const str = "";
return str || "Hello"
```

The second solution:

```
const str = "";
return (!!str) || "Hello"; // !!str is Boolean
```

The third solution:

```
const str = "";
return (+str) || "Hello"; // !!str is Boolean
```

Comment: The third solution is basically wrong when input is not a number, so that parsing result will be `NaN` which is also `falsy`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea too to check that you are not trying to pass an undefined term.

```
function TestMe() {
  if((typeof str != 'undefined') && str) {
    alert(str);
  }
 };

TestMe();

var str = 'hello';

TestMe();
```

I usually run into the case where I want to do something when a string attribute for an object instance is not empty.  Which is fine, except that attribute is not always present.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way, but I believe [bdukes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript/154068#154068) is best.

```
var myString = 'hello'; 
if(myString.charAt(0)){
    alert('no empty');
}
alert('empty');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using core (read vanilla) javascript we can leverage Object.is() for strict equality comparison. Following is a code snippet.

```
function validateString(arg) {
 if (Object.is(arg, "") || Object.is(arg, null) || Object.is(arg, undefined)) {
      return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript spec: https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-object.is

Here is the Mozilla Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some custom functions I use for handling this.  Along with examples of how the code runs.

```js
const v1 = 0
const v2 = '4'
const v2e = undefined
const v2e2 = null
const v3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const v3e = []
const v4 = true
const v4e = false
const v5 = {
  test: 'value'
}
const v5e = {}
const v6 = 'NotEmpty'
const v6e = ''

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
}

function isEmpty(v, zeroIsEmpty = false) {
  /**
   * When doing a typeof check, null will always return "object" so we filter that out first
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#typeof_null
   */
  if (v === null) {
    return true
  }

  if (v === true) {
    return false
  }

  if (typeof v === 'object') {
    return !Object.keys(v).length
  }

  if (isNumeric(v)) {
    return zeroIsEmpty ? parseFloat(v) === 0 : false
  }

  return !v || !v.length || v.length < 1
}

console.log(isEmpty(v1), isEmpty(v1, true))
console.log(isEmpty(v2), isEmpty(v2e), isEmpty(v2e))
console.log(isEmpty(v3), isEmpty(v3e))
console.log(isEmpty(v4), isEmpty(v4e))
console.log(isEmpty(v5), isEmpty(v5e))
console.log(isEmpty(v6), isEmpty(v6e))
```

Also for reference, here's [the source for Lodash isEmpty](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isEmpty.js):

Answer (score 0):

complete example. use `Object.keys()` for types `string`,`array`, and `object`

```js
function isEmpty(input){
    switch(typeof input){
      case 'undefined': return true
      case 'string':
      case 'object':
         return Object.keys(input).length == 0
      case 'boolean':
      case 'bigint':
      case 'number': return input == 0
    }
}
function log(...logs){
   for(let i = 0;i < logs.length;i++){
     if(i % 2 == 1){
        console.log(logs[i - 1],'=', logs[i])
     }
   }
}
log(
   isEmpty(),      'empty undefined',   // true
   isEmpty(''),    'empty string',      // true
   isEmpty('abc'), 'empty string',      // false
   isEmpty([]),    'empty array',       // true
   isEmpty([2,3]), 'empty array',       // false
   isEmpty({}),    'empty object',      // true
   isEmpty({a: 'abc'}), 'empty object', // false
   isEmpty(false), 'empty boolean',     // true
   isEmpty(true),  'empty boolean',     // false
   isEmpty(0n),    'empty bigint',      // true
   isEmpty(2n),    'empty bigint',      // false
   isEmpty(0),     'empty number',      // true
   isEmpty(2),     'empty number'       // false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use such approach

```
[null, undefined, ''].includes(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var x ="  ";
var patt = /^\s*$/g;
isBlank = patt.test(x);
alert(isBlank); // Is it blank or not??
x = x.replace(/\s*/g, ""); // Another way of replacing blanks with ""
if (x===""){
    alert("ya it is blank")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, the simplest function to check this is...

`const checkEmpty = string => (string.trim() === "") || !string.trim();`

Usage:

```
checkEmpty(""); // returns true.
checkEmpty("mystr"); // returns false.
```

It's that dead simple. :)

Comment: This will return true, even for strings that aren't empty that contain whitespace, such as `"   "`

Comment: I agree, but most of the time you do need to make sure to escape these whitespaces e.g. name field.

Answer (score -11):

To check if it is empty:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
if(str === ''){alert("THE string str is EMPTY");}
```

To check if it is of type string:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
if(typeof(str) === 'string'){alert("This is a String");}
```

Comment: Wrong. `length` is  not `null`. `str = ''; str.length == 0` not `str.length == null`. But on the whole your approach is ok.

Comment: Checking the length property will cause the string primitive to be wrapped in a string object and checking for null is not correct either as it doesn't look for undefined (which is not the same thing). To test for an empty string, simply check it against "" (i.e. if(myString === ""))