# What is the difference between the Boolean object and the Boolean data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, types, boolean

> The Boolean type has two literal
>   values: true and false.
>
> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean
>   values true and false with the true
>   and false values of the Boolean
>   object. The Boolean object is a
>   wrapper around the primitive Boolean
>   data type. See Boolean Object for more
>   information.

What does this mean? What's the difference between the Boolean object and the Boolean data type??

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I still don't understand when you'd want to use one rather than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a boolean value:

```
true
```

This is a Boolean object wrapping the value:

```
new Boolean(true);
```

Having the object adds a level of indirection. Try this to see the difference:

```
var a = true;
var b = true;
var c = new Boolean(true);
var d = new Boolean(true);

alert(a == b); // true - two `true` values are equal.
alert(c == d); // false - they are not the same object.
```

See also:

- [What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-javascript-new-boolean)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't understand when you'd want to use one rather than the other.

Comment: @DarkLightA: I suggest you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-javascript-new-boolean

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to other answers that a Boolean object can also be `null`, but a boolean value cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean data type is a value that can only be true or false. The Boolean object is an object that represents a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean Data Type is the 'boolean' (TRUE or FALSE) whereas the Boolean Object is an object that translates values INTO boolean data

You'll find an explanation here

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_boolean.asp)