# What is the difference between Boolean.TRUE and true in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

PS: I understand the difference between "true" and true.

Edit:
I also understand that Boolean.TRUE is a wrapper for the primitive true, my question then is - why does the primitive boolean accept Boolean.TRUE as a value?
For instance,

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

seems to be a valid statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531767/what-is-the-difference-between-the-boolean-object-and-the-boolean-data-type-in-ja

Comment: The link doesn't answer why `boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;` is a valid, meaningful statement. I say meaningful because it does what it looks like it does :)

Comment: That is because the link addressed the question you asked prior to editing.

Comment: I also made the comment after my edit - I was just clarifying that it wasn't what I was looking for. I wasn't saying you were wrong - I was just saying I wasn't looking for what you linked to.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

works is because of *autounboxing*, a Java 5 feature that allows a wrapper object to be converted to its primitive equivalent automatically when needed. The opposite, *autoboxing*, is also possible:

```
Boolean boolVar = true;
```

Comment: Excellent - I forgot all about autounboxing! But why have Boolean.TRUE in the first place?

Comment: @user183037: So you can use the object directly when you need to rather than having to go through autoboxing. As far as the constant itself, you want all instances of `Boolean` in a system to be one of two objects, `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`. As long as you don't use the constructor for `Boolean`, this is the case.

Comment: More to the point, you want only a single Boolean object in the VM with a `true` value. Similarly for `false`. In other words, two Boolean objects that are `equal()` are also `==`--that is, the same (identical) object.

Comment: @Ted: Yes, that's pretty much what I was saying.

Comment: So much for "Java does not support operator overloading." This is exactly what operator overloading would have achieved...

Answer (score 36):

As the previous answers stated, `Boolean.TRUE` returns the **wrapper** object of the boolean value `true`, so for the contexts where we need to treat boolean's like objects (for example, having an `ArrayList` of booleans), we could use `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`

As for why:

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

is valid is because of [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

In short, the Java compiler, when it sees you treating a primitive like an object, such as

```
List<Boolean> listOfBoolean = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
boolean someBool = true;
listOfBoolean.add(someBool);
```

it will automatically wrap it, or **autobox** it

```
List<Boolean> listOfBoolean = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
boolean someBool = true;
listOfBoolean.add(Boolean.valueOf(someBool));
```

And if it sees you treating a wrapper object, like `Boolean.TRUE`, as a primitive, like:

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

it will convert it down into a primitive, or **unbox** it, like if we did:

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue();
```

Once upon a time, you'd have to do this by hand, but now, for better or for worse, this is mostly taken care of for you.

And if you're wondering why have `Boolean.TRUE` at all, it's because there is no need to have floating around lots of Boolean objects for `true`. Since a boolean can only be one of two values, it's simpler just to have them as constants rather than, for every time someone needs boxed up `true`:

```
Boolean trueBool = new Boolean(true);
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to accept 2 answers, so I accepted Colin's as he posted earlier, but your detailed explanation made a lot of sense - thank you!

Comment: @user183037 That's fine, I'm just glad to help :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Boolean.TRUE** is a wrapper object and singleton . **true** is a literal constant. Below are 2 situations where I use wrappers over primitives

1. I want to store them in Collections
2. I'd want to have a notion of **null**. primitive boolean can only represent two states.

Answer (score 3):

`true` is of the primitive `boolean` type while `Boolean.TRUE` is a [`Boolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) object that wraps the `true` value.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types, (e.i. `boolean`), are strongly preferred over classes (e.i. `Boolean`) for a number of reasons. See discussion here. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203970/when-to-use-primitive-vs-class-in-java. Primitive type makes code more readable, prevents pointer errors, such as `if(a==b)` vs `if(a.equals(b))`, increases performance and follows the conversion.

There is one case when `Boolean` or `Integer` works better than `boolean` and `int`.  That is if you have a situation when you want to allow `null` as a value. This results in a number of null checks, but it prevents `false` from slipping through when

Answer (score 0):

Boolean.TRUE is a reference to an object of the class Boolean, while true is just a value of the primitive boolean type.  Classes like Boolean are often called "wrapper classes", and are used when you need an object instead of a primitive type (for example, if you're storing it in a data structure).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get an explanation on the link from Wikipedia below.

All of the primitive wrapper classes in Java are immutable. J2SE 5.0 introduced autoboxing of primitive types into their wrapper object, and automatic unboxing of the wrapper objects into their primitive value—the implicit conversion between the wrapper objects and primitive values.

More on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class