# Why change boolean primitive value into a boolean object reference?

Tags: java, reference, boolean, primitive

I am reading Effective Java and in the first chapter the first example changes a boolean primitive value into a boolean object reference:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) 
{
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the different between boolean primitive value and boolean object reference?
2. What is the reason to do this?

Comment: I'm very sure the answer is also in that book, if your read on... So why don't you read on? ;-)

Comment: you can check the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894311/what-is-the-difference-between-boolean-true-and-true-in-java

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use primitives in generics. You cannot do this:

```
List<boolean> x;
```

but you can do this:

```
List<Boolean> x;
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question, though, since the generic type would be a compile-time constant, not something returned from a function.

Comment: I think it does answer the question, it explains one difference between primitive and boxed booleans, and also explains a purpose for boxing booleans. Those were he questions, am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose we could comment on why the author chose to explicitly return `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`, as opposed to `new Boolean(true)` etc. (because `new Boolean(true)` creates unnecessary object instances btw).

Comment: `BitSet` would generally be better.

Comment: It doesn't explain the purpose for the conversion, because the conversion isn't relevant for a generic declaration. Nor is a declaration a reference. What you say is correct, of course, but there's no boxing in your example, nor values.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the primitive **boolean** has two possible values: **true** or **false**.  The object Boolean has three:  **true**, **false**, and **null**.   That is sometimes very useful.

Comment: Mostly for accidentally generating NPEs. Anyway, you can create an enum of `True`, `False` and `FileNotFound`.

Comment: Why would your getter method return a **null**?  Usually the null value can be used to indicate "not initialized" without having to have a separate boolean property for that.

Comment: +1: I've found that "third value" to be particularly useful every once in a while!

Comment: ...and very confusing. Why isn't it called threelean then?

Answer (score 1):

A primitive cannot be used in all contexts.  For instance, when used in any of the collection classes, an object type is required.  This is mostly done for you, anyway, by auto-boxing.  But you should still know about it, or you will get bitten at one point.

Another thing is that an object type can contain null.  In cases where you need to differentiate between true, false and unknown, using `Boolean` can be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

1> `Boolean` is [wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) for `boolean`

> Wrapper classes are used to represent primitive values when an Object
>   is required. **Wikipedia**

wrapper `class` is used to apply some methods and calculation, which is not possible using primitive data types.

2> it depends upon situations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most common uses for `Boolean` are for use in generic function object and, unfortunately, reflection.

For instance:

```
boolean exists = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new PrivilegedAction<>() {
        public Boolean run() {
            return file.exists();
        }
    }
);
```

(Probably less boilerplate in Java SE 8.)