# Is there any reason for "Boolean.TRUE.equals(x)" in Java?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I've come across this code in one of the projects I'm working on

(This is in Java)

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(foo.isBar()))
```

**Foo#isBar()** is defined as `boolean isBar()`, so it can't return `null`

Is there really any reason why it should be written that way?
I myself would just write

```
if (foo.isBar())
```

, but perhaps I'm missing something subtle.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps foo.isBar() could return null?

Comment: @KDiTraglia No, isBar() returns `boolean` (NOT `Boolean`)

Comment: It is more robust to compare to `Boolean.TRUE` if someone might change `foo.isBar()` to return `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.   Yogendra Singh's answer explains.

Comment: Perhaps `foo.isBar()` used to return `Boolean` before someone changed the return type to `boolean`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since `isBar` returns a primitive `boolean`, there is no semantic difference. Additionally, the second way is more concise, more clear, and more efficient, since the result won't have to be autboxed for the call and then have the original boolean extracted again. Given all that, there is no reason to use the first method, and several to use the second, so use the second.  I give a great deal of leeway to fellow coders, but I would sit down and have a chat with anyone who added something like that to professional code.

Comment: +1 Is similar to `if (true == foo.isBar())` or `if (isTrue(foo.isBar()))` They are needlessly verbose. I am not sure why some people prefer this. Perhaps some people prefer something which read more like English and find this reassuring.

Answer (score 40):

I hope `foo.isBar()` returns a boolean. In that case you can always write `if (foo.isBar())`.  If you `foo.isBar()` returns `Boolean` then it can be either `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE` or `NULL`. In that case `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(foo.isBar()))` makes sure the if block is executed in one scenario(TRUE) and omitted in remaining 2.

**Over and above**  `if (foo.isBar())` **will fail, when** `foo.isBar()` **returns Boolean NULL.**

Comment: So what will Boolean.TRUE.equals(foo.isBar()) return if foo.isBar() return null? Would it convert null to false or would it allow the boolean to be null?

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE.equals(null)` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Be careful with Boolean object, Boolean.FALSE.equals(null) is false but it does not mean it's true.
!Boolean.TRUE.equals(var) is not the same as Boolean.FALSE.equals(var) because of the null posibility.

Answer (score 8):

I would suspect "old legacy code with no good reason" - and in fact, I would contend it is *worse*. (I wonder how `int`s are compared ..)

The code that uses `TRUE.equals` requires a boxing conversion, an additional method call (and everything inside) and, in the end, it *just looks sloppy*.

---

The only reason I am aware of is if `foo.isBar` *was* typed as returning `Boolean` (not `boolean`) and where it may return `null`:

```
Boolean b = null;

// throws an exception when it tries to unbox b because it is null
boolean isTrue1 = (boolean)b;

// evaluates to false
boolean isTrue2 = Boolean.TRUE.equals(b);

// evaluates to false as well
boolean isTrue3 = b != null ? (boolean)b : false;
```

Comment: isBar() returns a `boolean` (primitive value)

Comment: yes, for some reason one sees a lot of these in pre-java5 code. Or written by programmers who did a lot of C coding in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Did I find this practical example, can be useful to someone:

When boxed type java.lang.Boolean is used as an expression it will throw `NullPointerException` if the value is `null` as defined in [Java Language Specification §5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

It is safer to avoid such conversion altogether and handle the null value explicitly.

**Noncompliant Code Example**

```
Boolean b = getBoolean();
if (b) {  // Noncompliant, it will throw NPE when b == null
  foo();
} else {
  bar();
}
```

**Compliant Solution**

```
Boolean b = getBoolean();
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)) {
  foo();
} else {
  bar();  // will be invoked for both b == false and b == null
}
```

Answer (score -4):

in the first condition you are checking for the equality of Boolean object corresponding to true.
and you are using the first condition in your code because your java version doesn't support autounboxing hence you need to use the boolean object.

[What is the difference between Boolean.TRUE and true in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894311/what-is-the-difference-between-boolean-true-and-true-in-java)

Comment: I know the difference between the two. I just wasn't sure why someone would do that since `isBar()` returns a primitive `boolean`

Comment: if it returns primitive than there is no reason.