# Is there any reason to do boolean casting with !! instead of Boolean() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am aware of Boolean(), String() and Number() casting, and the `'' + ...`, `!!...` and `+...` casting approaches.

I am wondering if there is any reason to **not** use the function constructors?

Comment: `!!` and others are unintentional syntactic sugar. I prefer the constructor approach as it is more readable. If you run it through a compressor/minifier, it can convert it into the uglier yet more compact version.

Comment: `!!` is perfectly readable in my opinion. I prefer those shortcuts.

Comment: No, both methods produce the same result.

Comment: @pimvdb Imagine you've just read 500 lines of code and you come to `x=!!0;` for example. Then look at this: `x = new Boolean(0);`. You really think `!!0` is more readable?

Comment: @Travis: That's a bad example to be honest. That one looks ugly because that are just four ugly tokens together. Also you just remove the spaces in the first one. I mean, e.g. `!!someVariable` is really compact and nice.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript).

Comment: @Travis `Boolean(0)`, not `new Boolean(0)`.

Comment: @pimvdb So you propose I should do `var x = 0; !!x` ? You're changing the semantics. Sorry, you're wrong. I bet you think Perl is a beautiful language.

Comment: @Travis: One-letter variables are perhaps not a good example, but the one I stated is preferable for me. But that's just my opinion :) I guess you like XML with all the typing?

Comment: There's a difference between which is more compact and which better conveys the intentions of the programmer. I bet you could ask fresh CS grads if they know what the purpose of `!!` is and at least half wouldn't know. My point being: `Boolean(x)` more clearly conveys what is trying to be achieved than `!!x`.

Comment: To be fair Andrew, most fresh CS grads wouldn't know what a prototypical language is either.

Comment: The `!!` and such are also available in other languages like PHP, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the use of `!!` is often discouraged, as it's not clear to those who haven't seen it before what the actual purpose of it is. That said, it is less than a third the characters of `Boolean()`.

Further, I'm not sure how often you actually need to cast to a boolean in Javascript, as it is often implicitly cast since Javascript is weakly typed.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm not super-sure I want somebody to mess with my code anyway if they're not familiar enough with JavaScript to know what "!!" means. :-)

Comment: @pointy, I think there's probably plenty of good programmers who just haven't been exposed to `!!` and wouldn't know what it's trying to do without either stopping to think about it or looking it up. I don't think I've ever seen `!!` used in JS, most of the time it's in C/C++.

Comment: Personally, as a hobby programmer I've come it across quite a many times. I understand your point, though. I guess whether or not to use `!!` depends on the code guidelines one has got to obey to.

Comment: I'm not 100% serious about that, but I do think that even great programmers unfamiliar with JavaScript should really study it, because there are a **lot** of landmines - particularly for long-time Java or C# programmers who've grown to see the world that way ...

Comment: @primvdb: Definitely. @Pointy I agree, there's definitely quite a bit about Javascript that trips up a lot of those unfamiliar with the language (`==` vs `===`, implicit `;`, etc.), especially if they consider it "just a browser scripting language".

Comment: I agree with @Pointy. Further, it is possible for the Boolean constructor to be modified while the "!" operator is immutable. Use !!. It is terse and means the same thing across many languages. I agree that for a single-language developer this could give pause; however, that's how one learns. Teaching and coaching less experienced developers is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `new` operator with those function constructors can have unreliable effects on the `typeof` operator. (Edit: As the comments correctly note, this is only when using `new Boolean()` instead of `Boolean()`)

For example,

```
var f = new Boolean(true);
if(typeof(f)==="boolean") {//false, since its an object, not boolean
 ....
}
```

[JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof) has some great examples.

Comment: Without the `new` keyword it works fine though. `typeof Boolean(1) === "boolean"`.

Comment: The OP was referring to `Boolean()`, not `new Boolean()`. Those are two different things. Also, `new` is an operator, not a constructor.

Comment: @Sime Vidas fixed, and added a clarification that it doesn't apply for cases where `new` isn't used. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 7:

1. B
2. o
3. o
4. l
5. e
6. a
7. n

Answer (score 2):

This *shouldn't* be an issue, but someone could replace the `Boolean` function with their own making the two ways not equivalent. For example:

```
Boolean = function(x) {
    alert('Evil');
    return !x; // Oops
}

var x = 0;
console.log(!!x); // false
console.log(Boolean(x)); // true
```

That's mostly a theoretical difference, since you shouldn't be replacing built in constructors, but it is a difference.

There *could* also be a *small* performance difference because of the name lookup and function call overhead. I wouldn't worry about either of those though in most cases. Just use whichever version you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It might just be a case of using less characters, making for a more compact script.

Answer (score 0):

I find using `new` with these types can lead to easy confusion or tricky bugs:

```
var x = new Boolean(true);
console.log( x ); // true
console.log( typeof x ); // "object"

var y = new Boolean('false');
console.log( y ); // true
console.log( typeof y ); // "object"

var z = false;
console.log( z ); // false
console.log( typeof z ); // "boolean"
```

Comment: Just using `Boolean(...)` is actually the question if I'm not wrong. That also returns correct `typeof` results.

Comment: `typeof ( new Boolean(false) ) === "object"`, whereas `typeof false === "boolean"`. I think the implicit version is therefore less opaque. I suppose it's a matter of preference.