# What's the point of the Boolean object?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am reading through the Mozilla Manual on JavaScript, and I come to this point in my reading, [Boolean object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean). I can't see a single use for them. What's their point? Why wouldn't you use just `true` and `false`?

By the way, I don't know Java at all and I'm not afraid of learning new things that consequently why I'm trying to learn JavaScript. I'm a PHP programmer, a back end guy, and I'd like to learn how to do some front end work, so I'm reading the [Mozilla JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: See also [What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/856324/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Because this is (somewhat sadly) how the language was defined** -- I suspect it was originally for performance/optimization; note the case of assignment to a `string` property below. (Java works similarly, although Scala and Python largely reject this distinction).

Note that `Boolean` isn't the only "wrapper type". There are also `String` and `Number`, for instance.

Because of this there remains a number of quirks (the below could just as much apply to Boolean):

```
typeof("foo") // string
typeof(new String("foo")) // object
"foo" instanceof String // false
new String("foo") instanceof String // true

// result is undefined: a string is a primitive and silently "ate" the assignment
// this also makes it a much cheaper value as it's not a "real" object
x = "f"; x.bar = 42; x.bar

// result is 42: a String is a "real" object with real properties!
// however, this also means that it may have a good bit more overhead
x = new String("f"); x.bar = 42; x.bar
```

I know this didn't "answer" the question, but rather chucks some more wood on the fire ;-)

The only real "gotcha" otherwise from the above is that perhaps `new Boolean(false)` is a truth-y value.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript language design has quite many dusty corners, and the Boolean is one of them; it is not used in practice.

This:

```
var a = [];
alert(a instanceof Array);
```

will tell you "true". But this:

```
var b = true;
alert(b instanceof Boolean);
```

for some reason will show "false".

In short: forget about it.

Comment: It's not just "some reason", the reason is that `true` is primitive, while `Boolean` is object. It's same as `1 instanceof Number == false`

Answer (score 6):

Creating a new boolean object "basically" runs the bit of code in the statement and then from there returns the true boolean value.

From the same docs:

```
1 var b = new Boolean(false);
2 if (b) // this condition evaluates to true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement

Comment: So, it allows me to hook into the if statement without having the call that object's methods explicitly because it is done so intrinsically? What method would I think over write to get this functionality, it's constructor?

Comment: Correct way to obtain the value of a boolean Object is `b.valueOf()`.
`if (b)` is always true for any object, even `if ({}) ...` is true.

Answer (score 5):

```
Boolean.prototype.bang = function() {
    return !this.valueOf();
}

true.bang(); // false
```

Everything in JavaScript is an object. But at the same time we also have primitives. It's really confusing, just don't overthink it.

Comment: This is really interesting! `true instanceof Boolean // false` but extending Boolean object affects it. Can you add links for more info? This is quite challenging to search for.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps because JavaScript objects are extensible in ways that primitives aren't? (I'm just guessing here, I've never had a need for Boolean.

Comment: No, that’s not true. Given `Boolean.prototype.someMethod = () => console.log(1);`, `true.someMethod();` is exactly the same as `Object(true).someMethod();` and `new Boolean(true).someMethod()` and `Boolean.prototype.someMethod.call(true)`, etc., and works just fine. Property access always coerces the left-hand value to an object.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean
>   values true and false with the true
>   and false values of the Boolean
>   object. Any object whose value is not
>   undefined , null, 0, NaN, or the empty
>   string , including a Boolean object
>   whose value is false, evaluates to
>   true when passed to a conditional
>   statement.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
if(SomeBoolean){...}
```

will be true in scenarios where `SomeBoolean` is a Boolean object.

Conversely:

```
if(false){...}
```

will **always** be false

Addendum for clarification.

```
var someString = new Boolean("MyNonEmptyString")
if(someString) //true
var otherString = new Boolean("")
if(otherString) //false
```

Comment: That seems to argue why you *shouldn't* use the Boolean object, not why you should.

Comment: I don't like the example. `SomeBoolean` will always be true where it is a Boolean object, or where it has been assigned a "truthy" value. The "converse" case isn't really converse, it should be `if (false)` will always be false.

Comment: @RobG for you I changed it to false and contrapositive.

Comment: This seems to be in contrast with other answers. The last condition, `if(otherString)`,  is `true` for me: http://jsbin.com/ijixi3

Comment: @Kobi my declaration of `""` should translate into the empty string.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - I'm not sure I understand... Did you try running your code? I get `true` on `if(otherString) //false`.

Comment: @Kobi no I did not run the code, because in every language I have ever used `""` is equal to `empty string`.  Furthermore the link you provided me I refuse to go to because that opens me up quite nicely to XSS.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Of course `""` is an empty string. I asked if you run the code that you wrote. Any way, never mind, but you are wrong (and have a fuzzy idea of what XSS is, but that's another matter `:)`).

Comment: @Kobi I am not even getting into the argument with you over what XSS is and is not.  Go complain to the implementors of JavaScript if their documentation is incorrect.

Comment: `otherString` evaluates to `true` as you are actually coercing an object to a boolean, which is always true for any object. Though the real value of it is indeed false`otherString.valueOf() == false`

Answer (score 2):

You can coerce a true or false from any value with `return Boolean(something)`, but it's shorter to write `return !!something`, which forces a true or false as well.

Comment: Good detail with the forcing of a `true` of `false` return value with `!!`. +1, but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to side with most of the people here that there isn't much need for the Boolean object, but I do want to point out a couple of things.

An explicit comparison will still evaluate like a boolean:

```
var someBool = new Boolean(false);
if (someBool == false)
    alert('Got here'); //Alerts 'Got here'
```

Because of this, you could *sort of* extend it to a subclass and still be able to have the comparison work as above:

```
var classExtension = {
    toYN: function() {
        return this == false ? 'N' : 'Y';
    }
};

function getNewClass(val) {
    var newBool = new Boolean(val);
    jQuery.extend(newBool, classExtension);
    return newBool;
}

var newTest = getNewClass(false);
if (newTest)
    alert('It\'s alive');
if (newTest == false)
    alert('And still a bool');
alert(newTest.toYN());
```

This will alert 'It's alive', 'And still a bool' and 'N'.
http://jsfiddle.net/fkJuk/

But again, would you ever really need this? Even if you did, it would probably be better just to have your own separate class with a boolean property that gets checked. In the end, it's probably here for consistency; every primitive has direct constructor and prototype access in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the specification (ECMA-262.pdf page 151), note that when Boolean is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it does type conversion. Thus:

```
var t = 5
  , f = 0

console.log(Boolean(t))  //Prints true
console.log(Boolean(f))  //Prints false
```

Of course, being a JavaScript object, you can use it as a prototype using the 'new' operator, as others have noted, but I don't see any reason for doing that.