# What practical use is a Boolean object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given that in JavaScript

```
console.log("var F=new Boolean(false)")
console.log("( F != (F==false))",(( F != (F==false)) ? "TRUE" : "false"));
console.log("(!F != (F==false))",((!F != (F==false)) ? "TRUE" : "false"));
```

prints:

```
( F != (F==false)) TRUE
(!F != (F==false)) TRUE
```

which means that Boolean objects are not dop-in substitutes for a boolean primitive in typical conditions like:

```
if(someBoolean) ...  // always true
if(!someBoolean) ... // always false
```

And that JavaScript's `Set` and `Map` collections permit any type, including primitives.

What use are Boolean objects, in particular; and the objects representing other primitive types in general, since they have all sort of weird in consistencies associated with them?

Note: I am specifically asking **what are the use-cases** (if any), not **how they are different from their primitive counterparts**.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript) post may provide some insight. I'm not flagging it as a dup as it is 7 years old, and may be out of date

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript — Does this help ?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132949/whats-the-point-of-the-boolean-object FWIW, WeakMap keys must be objects, i.e. `(new WeakMap).set(true, "foo")` raises an error whereas `(new WeakMap).set(Boolean(true), "foo")` does not.

Comment: @askerovlab: Not really. The answers there discuss the differences and some of the traps, but not the pragmatic use-cases for the object(s).

Comment: I don't really think there are any *practical* uses. [Try finding anything that isn't just testing compatibility](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&p=1&q=%22new+Boolean%22&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) either with a framework or an engine. Oriol points out what you *can* do with it but I wouldn't exactly call such things practical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Boolean objects are just objects, and thus are truthy.

```js
console.log(!!new Boolean(true)); // true
console.log(!!new Boolean(false)); // true
```

Boolean objects exist because this way you can add methods to `Boolean.prototype` and use them on primitive booleans (which will be wrapped into booolean objects under the hood).

```js
Boolean.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log("I'm the boolean " + this + "!!");
};
true.foo();
false.foo();
```

They are also useful when you want to store properties in a boolean.

```js
var wrappedBool = new Boolean(false);
wrappedBool.foo = "bar";
console.log("Property foo: ", wrappedBool.foo); // "bar"
console.log("Unwrapped bool: ", wrappedBool.valueOf()); // false
```

But that's not recommended.

Comment: Please explain "truthy" or provide reference. Why does the first example make any kind of sense?

Comment: Truthy just means that isn't `null, false, undefined, 0, or empty`. `true === {}` true, but `true === "" ` is false

Comment: @ThisClark Truthy means that, when coerced to a boolean, it becomes `true`. The double not `!!` or the `Boolean` function are the standard ways to coerce a value to a boolean. All values are truthy except the primitives `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `-0`, `+0`, `NaN`, `""`.

Comment: Also the Boolean object allows you to use it's valueOf method to do what the OP was asking. Where the original object will return truthy, the value that's returned from the method will determine truthy or falsy correctly. var F = new Boolean(false);  console.log(!F.valueOf()); // true

Comment: That's not why Boolean objects can have properties. All objects can have properties, that's not deliberate. That's inherent.  All except for null. The null is: not-an-object object. Analogous to the number NaN, therefore it cannot accept properties. So no, Boolean objects don't exist so you can add methods to them.

Comment: @BekimBacaj I mean that if boolean objects didn't exist, primitive booleans wouldn't be object-coercible. In that case you wouldn't be able to add methods to `Boolean.prototype` and call them on primitive booleans.

Answer (score 4):

Say we have...

```
var F = new Boolean(); 
var f = false;
```

Where **F** is an ***object*** and **f** is a ***primitive***.

**Objects are passed by *reference*. Primitives are passed by *value***.

Whatever the *type* of an *object* is, it always retains its individuality; identity.  It behaves like a real (material) object, taking its own unique space in the Universe.

Therefore...

```
var Fn = new Boolean();
```

is not 'equal' to F, even when comparing with dynamic type operator '==' even-though they are of the same type and carry the same value:

```
Fn == F; 
>> false
```

That's because ( as already underlined ), they are two separate & different *objects* who carry items of the **same value**, ie., *false*.  Which is nonetheless - *not the same **false***.

And, because there's no type conversion ( since they are of the same type already ) they will be compared by reference - which are obviously pointing to two separate objects, ***meaning:*** they are not the same object!

We should imagine our JavaScript objects of a given type as packets specifically designed to carry a certain type of valuables. This way of thinking will make it far easier to understand even the most unexpected results of our work. And this is why ***null*** is beautiful.

The use case of a practical value (would have been), that a certain Boolean object can carry both values but remain the same (identifiable) object. Alas the Boolean object has been left at its initial, introduction state in JavaScript development. And is now practically useless and can only be used to determine that this false:true value comes from a different process and *return* than the one you are comparing it too.

Regards.