# Boolean coercion fails

Tags: javascript, boolean, coercion

I am wondering why the Boolean coercion fails in this case:

```
!!(new Boolean(false)) === true
```

Although:

```
(new Boolean(false).valueOf())  === false
```

[Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#boolean_coercion):

> Booleans are returned as-is.

I am wondering what "as-is" means in the context of a coercion. I thought "coercion" means "convert anything to a primitive boolean". How is it possible that something which is meant to be false gets coerced to true?

BTW: Consequently this fails too:

```
Boolean(new Boolean(false)) === true
```

Comment: Because `typeof new Boolean(false) === 'object'`. Remove `new` to get a primitive boolean value from `Boolean`.

Comment: an object/instance is always truthy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the `Boolean` class itself is an error. Maybe I have to use the following code:

```js
if (arg instanceof Boolean)
    throw new Error("Stop doing nonsense")
```

Or maybe this:

```js
function coerce_boolean_correctly (arg) {
  if (arg instanceof Boolean)
    return coerce_boolean_correctly(arg.valueOf())
  return !!arg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between a Boolean object and a Boolean primitive. The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#boolean_coercion) you referenced, actually warns about this at the very outset:

> Do not confuse the primitive `Boolean` values `true` and `false` with the `true` and `false` values of the `Boolean` object.
>
> Any object, **including a `Boolean` object whose value is `false`**, evaluates to `true` when passed to a conditional statement.

And this (what I marked in bold) is exactly what happens in your code: it creates a `new Boolean(false)` and that will coerce to `true` -- in other words it is a *truthy* value. In your code you have explicitly converted it to a boolean primitive, by applying `!` to it twice. In either case (implicit coercion or explicit conversion) `new Boolean(false)` is truthy. Fact is that **all** objects are considered truthy (when coerced to boolean, they evaluate to `true`).

The article continues with:

> Do not use the `Boolean()` constructor with new to convert a non-boolean value to a boolean value — use `Boolean` as a function or a double NOT instead.

This suggests that your code should be modified to drop the use of `new`, and call `Boolean` as a plain function, not as constructor:

```
!!(Boolean(false)) === false
```

When `Boolean` is called as plain function, it returns a primitive boolean (`false` or `true`). But anything that is called as constructor, even `Boolean`, will return an **object**. And objects are truthy.

When in the context of coercion MDN states *"Booleans are returned as-is."* they refer to boolean **primitives**. (Boolean) objects are covered by the last bullet point in the same list: *"All objects become `true`"*. The latter in includes `Boolean` objects.

A `Boolean` *object* has a `valueOf` method which returns a boolean primitive, and so it returns what you would intuitively expect.

The MDN article rightly says:

> **Warning:** You should rarely find yourself using `Boolean` as a constructor.

Don't use `new Boolean`, but `Boolean`.

If for some reason you have a `Boolean` object, really ask yourself why you have that object in the first place. Tackle the code that *created* that object and use a primitive boolean from the outset.

#### Objects are truthy

Some are surprised in a similar way that the following holds:

```js
if (!!new String("")) console.log("An empty string is truthy!?");
if (!!new Number(0)) console.log("The number 0 is truthy!?");
if (!!new Number(NaN)) console.log("NaN is truthy!?");
if (!!new Object(null)) console.log("null is truthy!?");
if (!!new Object(undefined)) console.log("Undefined is truthy!?");
```

It is the same principle: objects are truthy. Always.<sup>*</sup> No matter what their constructor is named. No matter what value was passed to that constructor.

<sub>* [`document.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy) is an abhorrent, but accepted, violation of this rule.</sub>

#### See also

- [What's the point of the Boolean object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132949/whats-the-point-of-the-boolean-object)
- [What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: The advise "do not use `new Boolean`" is no solution. In particular it is no solution for library code. The class `Boolean` should be removed from the language, because it is nonsense. It is nonsense to create a Boolean class, when all instances of this class are always true. This is totally misleading.

Comment: Which library code are you referring to?