# How many values can a boolean type have?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would have guessed only 2.  True/False.  Howerver from underscore.js check for Boolean types, we have:

```
_.isBoolean = function(obj) {
    return obj === true || obj === false || toString.call(obj) == '[object Boolean]';
  };
```

I would have thought checking for a value of true or false would have been sufficient, but b.c. of the 3rd operand

```
 toString.call(obj) == '[object Boolean]'
```

there must be other values?

Comment: There are `Boolean` **objects**, that are not equal to true or false

Comment: Then what's the point of their existence if they can't be equal to true/false?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: @the_web_situation Well, it's too late, too many people answered. Anyways, hopefully this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hxj7/

Comment: @the_web_situation I'm not sure they're actually *used* much, but from the examples the answers show, it's possible that a primitive be autoboxed to an Object, so this is just a safecheck for those slim chances. Because of short-circuiting, the extra check shouldn't be called except for those rare occasions

Comment: the only correct answer got deleted ... here is a real world example ... http://jsfiddle.net/tr2by/

Comment: Brilliant, where did answer #5 go ?

Comment: @the_web_situation I don't know, I think lonesomeday scared him off with with his incorrect claims. I was just commenting on the answer because lonesomeday's comment didn't make sense, and was trying to prove it was a good example

Answer (score 1):

The method checks to see if the value is either a boolean primitive (`true` or `false`) or if it's an instance of the Boolean built-in object type. In other words, there are two types involved, so it's checking for both.

Answer (score 1):

There are also [Boolean Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) which are not the same as the primitive (but still Boolean nonetheless):

```
new Boolean(false) == false // true
new Boolean(false) === false // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var bool = new Boolean();
```

This constructs a new [Boolean object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean). Now, presumably, a boolean must be `true` or `false`, correct?

```
bool === true; // returns false
bool === false; // returns false
```

So it's a boolean, but neither `true` nor `false`. This is the circumstace that underscore is catering for.

The reason is that it is a `Boolean` *object*. `true` and `false` are Javascript primitives. No object is ever equal to a primitive or indeed to any object other than itself.

Comment: @the_web_situation I can't imagine ever using this in my own code. Underscore is a library, however, so has to deal with the strange things programmers do. *shrug*