# Why new Boolean(false) is true?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand what's going on

```
var x=new Boolean(false)
if(x){
  console.log('plus')
}
console.log(x==false) //true
```

Why `if(x)` returns `true`    ?

Comment: Note that `x !== false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Says so in the docs:

> Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean
>   object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a
>   conditional statement. For example, the condition in the following if
>   statement evaluates to true

```
x = new Boolean(false);
if (x) {
  // ...this code is executed
}
```

Directly from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

Comment: only when  passed to a conditional statement ?

Comment: Well yes, but what else were you planning on using it for?

Comment: Good job literally copying the MDN and posting it as an answer. You may want to closevote the question as looking for a offsite resource, instead. The "Directly from MDN" line was edited in later...

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you. Did I not disclose that clearly enough for you? And as for you edit, absolutely not. That's not what the OP asked for, but I provided it as it answers the question. That would imply that other answers which *don't* reference the MDN docs would be deemed invalid - which is incorrect. Anyway, not the place for either of our comments. Go to meta if you feel the need to.

Comment: RGraham: looking over the "situation" again, (And admittedly, after a quick meta question), I understand why answers like this aren't necessarily a "bad" thing.

Answer (score 5):

See MDN docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean .

It is stated :

> Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean
>   object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a
>   conditional statement.

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as this:

`x` is a `Boolean` object. (Logging it will show: `Boolean {}`)

All objects evaluate to `true` (See the [first paragraph under "Description"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description))

Comment: `All objects evaluate to true` - While I know that it might be good to include a link to [**some documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) so users who don't know that have a reference to something they can continue learning from in the future. Difference between feeding someone and teaching them how to fish -- or what ever the saying is :). Just my personal preference

Answer (score 2):

`var x = new Boolean();`

when use the keyword `new` ,the variable created is an object type, object type value is always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Object is truthy.
See http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

so evaluating it without the implicit type conversion (when comparing to `false`) is true.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Boolean ***function*** incorrectly: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

What you're looking for is:

```
var x = false;
if (Boolean(x)){

}
```

However, since you already know x will be true or false, and you're not evaluating an expression to see if it's true or false (as per the link), you don't need the function Boolean()

Answer (score 0):

A Boolean class is not a primitive value.
when you check

```
if (someObject)
```

it will return true because

```
Boolean(someObject)
```

will always return true.

You have a couple of options here:
1.
Use

```
if (valueOf(x))
```

to get the primitive value again

2.
Remove the 'new' keyword

```
x = Boolean(false)
```

So you get the value of the Boolean function

---

Take a look at [What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript)