# Discord Bot doesn't loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, bots, discord

I want to loop the user until he/she guess but, it does crash for heading out of memory on Window PowerShell. I know that the reason is because it does do an infinite loop. I'm not an expert on Javascript, I'm just messing around with it.

````
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === "Vamos a jugar al ahorcado") {
        const channel = msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "chat-general");
        const filter = m => m.author.id === msg.author.id;
        var words = ["mosquito","cajuela","tambores", "rotonda", "esparatrapo", "zarpullido", "perjuicios", "transtorno", "veniste", "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", "apapachar", "inefable", "sapenco", "mamporrero", "desarrolladores", "aguja", "cascarabias", "jugueton", "zurcir", "ascensor", "sonrojado", "armadillo", "electrodomestico", "electroencefalografista", "ovoviviparo", "transustanciacion", "paralelepipedo", "delicuescencia", "otorrinolaringologo", "vocalizacion", "provocar", "desvertirse", "esparatrapo", "antihistaminico", "cronometro", "institucionalizacion", "indiosincrasia", "ventrilocuo", "tejemaneje", "anaranjada", "sanguijuela", "ronronear", "sacacorchos", "desarrollar", "quehaceres", "papeleria", "hamburguesa", "abrelatas", "calcetines", "escarabajo", "hermano", "remolacha", "escalera", "oferta", "loro", "sobrino", "tomate", "aletas", "esposa", "mayonesa", "repisa", "calzoncillo", "amarillo", "durazno", "biberon", "rabano", "espejo", "sandwich", "coliflor", "rocket-0", "tarkov", "peluqueria", "carnederes", "oferta", "basurero"];
        var userGuess = new Boolean(false);
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        var guessedSoFar = "```";
        var userInput = "";
        var n = new Boolean(false);
        var indexNumber = 0;
        var counter = 1;

        msg.reply('Vamos a jugar al ahorcado! A ver quien adivina esta? Escribe una letra continuacion!');
        wordGuess = words[index];

        for(i = 0; i < wordGuess.length; i++){
            guessedSoFar += "_ ";
        }
        guessedSoFar += "```";

        while(userGuess != true){
            msg.channel.send(guessedSoFar);
            msg.channel.send("Escribe una letra!");
            msg.channel.send(wordGuess);
            msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1, 
                time: 10000
            }).then(collected => {
                if(collected.first().content === "cancel"){
                    return msg.reply("Cancelled!");
                };

                userInput = collected.first().content;
                msg.channel.send("Dejame ver si '" + userInput + "' esta en la palabra...");
                n = wordGuess.includes(userInput);
                userGuess = false;

                if(n == true && userInput != wordGuess){
                    msg.channel.send("YIKES lo tienes");
                    indexNumber = wordGuess.indexOf(userInput);
                    guessedSoFar = guessedSoFar.replaceAt((indexNumber + 3), (" " + userInput + " "));

                } else if(userInput == wordGuess){
                    return msg.reply("Haz ganado!!! La palabara era " + wordGuess);
                }else {
                    msg.channel.send("NOPE");
                    userGuess = true;
                }
            });
            /*If I insert the following line here it doesn't crash and do just one loop. (I don't intent to do that, I want a loop until user Cancel or Guess Correctly).

            userGuess = true;*/
        }

    }
});
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD8fb.jpg)

Comment: Sidenote: I don't think you should be using: new Boolean(false) which returns an Object.
Use the value false instead. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258022/why-new-booleanfalse-is-true

Comment: You can't use `while` with promises. You should have a function like `requestGuess()` that, if the user guesses wrong, gets called again.