# Create JavaScript boolean variable

Tags: javascript

```
deletemode = new Boolean(false);

if(deletemode) alert("TRUE"); else alert("FALSE");

alert(deletemode);
```

I was hoping to see FALSE alert but I am seeing TRUE alert

I read MDN and it read

```
deletemode = new Boolean(true);
```

That is the way to create a false boolean variable

But when I run the statements above I see "TRUE" and then in the second alert I see false.

If I do this it does what I expect it to do

```
if(deletemode===false)
```

Is

```
if(deletemode)
```

a JavaScript syntax error?

Comment: That's looks like expected behavior according to MDN. See the first code example there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: On my browser, `deletemode === false` evaluates to `false`, not `true`.

Comment: @Alnitak I think he's talking about the case `if (deletemode)` returns `true`, which appears to be expected behavior.

Comment: He said _"if I do this it does what I expect it to do"_ then has the `if (deletemode == false`).

Comment: @Alnitak Sorry, I think I just misunderstood the context of your comment. I do see what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is unexpected is because `new Boolean(false)` returns an object. In JS, all objects evaluate to a truthy value. This is why your test alerted 'TRUE' since the 'if' construct simply checks whether the expression is truthy.

In addition, you should never create a boolean using the Boolean constructor function. Instead, just use the literal values, `true` or `false`.

Comment: true false are those string values?

Comment: No, true and false are literal boolean values. The strings 'true' and 'false' are string values.

Answer (score 3):

The `===` strict equality operator will return `false` since the `Boolean` object and the boolean literal are not strictly equal.  In fact, even this will return false, because the two newly created objects are not the same object:

```
new Boolean(true) === new Boolean(true)    // is false
```

However a `deletemode == false` test will return `true` because it will call the `.valueOf()` method on the object and get the value `false`, which therefore correctly compares equal to `false`.

The `alert()` function always calls `.toString()` on its parameter, therefore also displaying `false` instead of the default `[Object object]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find some answers in the following link. The short answer: using the new Boolean() constructor creates a wrapper around your value so that calling the variable always returns true. If all you want to do is store true/false, without any extra functions or logic on the variable holding the value, then you should probably just assign it directly. ie, var deletemode = false

[What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript)