# Why the following javascript statement evaluates to true?

Tags: javascript, object, boolean

Why the following if statement evaluates to true since the value is false?

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
if (x) {
  // this code is executed
}
```

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of new Boolean() in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856324/what-is-the-purpose-of-new-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: All objects are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does'nt evaluate to false, since it is an object. the Value of x is an object resulting out of the constructor function:

```
Boolean {[[PrimitiveValue]]: false}
```

Objects are allways truthy. instead try grabbing the actual value from your constructed object:

```
if(x.valueOf()){}
```

hope this helped

Comment: this would not work in this case though. The questioneer has created an Object from a constructor function an {} === true be falsy

Comment: i did. var test = new Boolean(true); test === true results in falsy return

Comment: === DOESNT coerce you mean == ... it works for == but coercing is kind of "unpredictable" (it in fact isnt unpredictable but reading the code it may get confusing) so you should not do it. I dont really get why he is using a constructor function to return a boolean anyway

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` has become an object, which is a [truthy value](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) (i.e not `false`).

try:

```
var x = false;
if (x) {
  // this code will not be executed 
} else {
  // this code will be executed instead
}
```

Be very careful with your types ;)