# What is the best way to test for an empty string with jquery-out-of-the-box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to test for an empty string with jquery-out-of-the-box, i.e. without plugins? I tried [this](http://zipalong.com/blog/?p=287).

But it did't work at least out-of-the-box. It would be nice to use something that's builtin.

I wouldn't like to repeat

```
if (a == null || a=='')
```

everywhere if some  `if (isempty(a))`   would be available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 601, accepted):

```
if (!a) {
  // is emtpy
}
```

To ignore white space for strings:

```
if (!a.trim()) {
    // is empty or whitespace
}
```

If you need legacy support (IE8-) for `trim()`, use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) or a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility).

Comment: but does this check for ""?   Doesn't that just check to see if it's null only and you need to also check for empty as empty is not the same as null?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict empty string is falsy in javascript, so yes, the expression evaluates to true if ``a`` is "" or any other falsy value (null, false, undefined, 0, NaN).

Comment: what about spaces? is that an empty string?

Comment: If you need to also match strings with only whitespace, it's a good idea to use `if (!$.trim(a))`

Comment: In my experience the vast majority of times you want to run this test you also want it to include testing for whitespace.  Since that is the usual-case, OP should include in his answer the comment from @IlariKajaste

Comment: The accepted answer will fail when you input a 0, however it will work for 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: how is `if (!a)` superior than `if (a !== "")`?

Comment: how could it be designed to accept any type if the question says "string"?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Then no, it’s not "superior", just simpler and less verbose. Both methods will do the job.

Comment: Isn't `if (!a.trim())` a bit dangerous? What if `a` is undefined or null?

Comment: @Timo "dangerous" is a vague concept here. The question was about testing for an empty *string*, so raising an exception for `undefined` or `null` is not dangerous at all, it’s actually preferred.

Comment: @David Sure, but I see no problem in adding a few more chars for improved practicality, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812245/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-with-jquery-out-of-the-box/33672308#33672308

Comment: @timo If you are worried about types, I would do a simple type check (since JavaScript is loosely typed): `if (typeof a != 'string') throw new TypeError(a+' is not a string')`. This would prevent bugs like `1+'1'` later on in your chain.

Comment: @Stevus `0` is not a *String*, which is what the OP asked. If you do this check on other types, you should be aware of JavaScript’s type coersion.

Comment: @David - `0` is not a string, yes, however there is no type checking in the if statement, so the `if(!a) {}` will evaluate to true. Now if you want to be sure it is a string, use something like `typeof a === 'string' && !a` or something.

Comment: @Stevus Validating functional arguments and type checking is not the job of the function itself IMO, but that is a design decision and kind of irrelevant to the original question. But your point is valid since some people might not be aware of javascripts type coersion strategy...

Answer (score 30):

The link you gave seems to be attempting something different to the test you are trying to avoid repeating.

```
if (a == null || a=='')
```

tests if the string is an empty string or null. The article you linked to tests if the string consists entirely of whitespace (or is empty).

The test you described can be replaced by:

```
if (!a)
```

Because in javascript, an empty string, and null, both evaluate to false in a boolean context.

Comment: `if(!a)` wont it fail for a string consisting of say 4 spaces ? `    `

Comment: @KNU Yes, but the question asks about an empty string, and a string comprising of spaces is not an empty string. See what I wrote about the difference between what was asked and what the linked code does

Comment: This answer is wrong. It treats '0' like an empty string, which it isn't.

Comment: @JohnHenckel: It'll treat `0` like an empty string, but not `"0"`. I assume that's what you meant? It's conceivable that this is being used in a situation where you know that `a` is either a string, or null, but yes. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 28):

Based on [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812245/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-with-jquery-out-of-the-box/33672308#1812253) I personally like to check the given object first if it is a string at all. Otherwise calling `.trim()` on a not existing object would throw an exception:

```
function isEmpty(value) {
  return typeof value == 'string' && !value.trim() || typeof value == 'undefined' || value === null;
}
```

Usage:

```
isEmpty(undefined); // true
isEmpty(null); // true
isEmpty(''); // true
isEmpty('foo'); // false
isEmpty(1); // false
isEmpty(0); // false
```

Comment: i check with <br /><p></p> from textarea and it said not empty as it should

Answer (score 6):

Check if data is a empty string (and ignore any white space) with jQuery:

```
function isBlank( data ) {
    return ( $.trim(data).length == 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!my_string){ 
// stuff 
}
```

and

```
if(my_string !== "")
```

if you want to accept null but reject empty

EDIT: woops, forgot your condition is if it IS empty

Answer (score 2):

Try executing this in your browser console or in a node.js repl.

```
var string = ' ';
string ? true : false;
//-> true

string = '';
string ? true : false;
//-> false
```

Therefore, a simple branching construct will suffice for the test.

```
if(string) {
    // string is not empty
}
```

Comment: it's better to say "!!string" instead of "string ? true : false" or even just "string".

Answer (score 2):

Since you can also input numbers as well as fixed type strings, the answer should actually be:

```
function isBlank(value) {
  return $.trim(value);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this? `return !!$.trim(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code by jQuery:

```
 if ($("#ItemId").val().trim() != "") {
            console.log($("#ItemId").val());
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if(!a || a.length === 0)
```

Comment: The OP specifically stated that they are looking for an alternative to this.

Answer (score -4):

```
if((a.trim()=="")||(a=="")||(a==null))
{
    //empty condition
}
else
{
    //working condition
}
```

Comment: If a is ``null`` then ``a.trim()`` would fail. This is a bad order to check things. And if you change the order, your answer does not provide anything, that has not been suggested before.