# when form value string empty dont add li class

Tags: javascript

```js
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
var itemList = document.getElementById('items');

// Form submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get input value
  var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;
  // Create new li element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  // Add text node with input value
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));
  // Create del button element
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  // Add classes to del button
  deleteBtn.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';
  // Append text node
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));
  // Append button to li
  li.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  // Append li to list
  itemList.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="header-title">Item Lister</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Items</h2>
    <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

im trying to add li class to an html which this code does great but how can i do it only when there is a value entered in the form and not empty string.
was thinkin of trying if statement with value === '' if condition true dont (there is also a button which im appending) else add classes.
thanks guys :)

Comment: For best way to test empty see this [so] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812245/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-with-jquery-out-of-the-box)

Comment: im trying to implement it to my code, so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition to check whether value is empty. If true, ignore remain code

```js
var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;
if (!newItem) {
  return;
}
```