# Why should I use string.length == 0 over string == "" when checking for empty string in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison, ecmascript-4

Most of the developers on my current project use a (to me) strange way to check for empty strings in ECMAScript:

```
if (theString.length == 0)
    // string is empty
```

I would normally write this instead:

```
if (theString == "")
    // string is empty
```

The latter version seems more readable and natural to me.

Nobody I asked seemed to be able to explain the advantages of version 1. I guess that at some time in the past somebody told everybody that this is the way to do it, but now that person left and nobody remembers why it should be done this way.

I'm wondering whether there is a reason why I should choose the first version over the second? Does it matter, is one version better than the other one? Is one version safer or faster for some reason?

(We actually do this in Siebel eScript which is compliant with ECMAScript Edition 4)

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I actually prefer that technique in a number of languages, since it's sometimes hard to differentiate between an empty string literal `""` and several other strings (`" "`, `'"'`).

But there's another reason to avoid `theString == ""` in ECMAScript: `0 == ""` evaluates to `true`, as does `false == ""` and `0.0 == ""`...

...so unless you *know* that `theString` is **actually a string**, you might end up causing problems for yourself by using the weak comparison. Fortunately, you can avoid this with judicious use of the strict equal (`===`) operator:

```
if ( theString === "" )
   // string is a string and is empty
```

#### See also:

- [**What is the best way to check for an empty string in JavaScript?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Ok, I did some tests, comparing the three methods (.length, ==, ===) with different variables: strings, numbers, booleans and undefined. .length and === give me the same results, except that .length generates an error when I try to use it with undefined. I think I'll start using === in my own code from now on. Thanks.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: question is largely a duplicate of the one I linked to in "See also". I didn't realize that prior to writing the answer, but after examining it I consider it adequate and don't particularly want to gain further rep from this. If anyone has an alternate solution or disputes this one, it would be helpful if they brought that information into the original question...

Comment: @Shog9: interesting, and rather big of you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if `theString` is set to `0` (zero) your 2nd example will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is correct and it's important to understand type checking. But as far as performance, a string compare is going to lose to .length method every time, but by a very very small amount. If you aren't interested in shaving milliseconds from your site speed, you may want to choose what is more readable / maintainable to you and , more importantly, your team.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/empty-string-vs-string-length and several others... so close that it is nearly negligible, but .length will win

Comment: When you have more rep, this should really go as a comment to the answer...  You'll get there in no time.

Comment: ya, still not sure how to get a 'rep' on here :-p But I my ego isn't so big either, so doesn't bother me too much. Just trying to spread the knowledge to my peers

Comment: I asked one question, got 18 'rep points', woohoo... man, I've used this site since it came out, or at least since 2010. Never understood the rep thing. I think I got it now, but I have to come up with strange questions (or maybe I come up with some I already know the answer to?) to get a reputation. It bothers me