# What's wrong with != '' in javascript (comparing to an empty string)?

Tags: javascript

jsbin started warning me that `x != ''` is not good, and I should replace it with `x !== ''`

Why?

Comment: Wow, just check out all the related questions. So many questions titled "What's wrong with this javascript code".

Comment: If you bothered to look up the difference between `!=` and `!==` then you'd have your answer in seconds. I expect more from a 12.7k user who's been here for over three years.

Comment: Closers - don't close a question based on the user. The question is valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I use string.length == 0 over string == "" when checking for empty string in ECMAScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829611/), [Implied string comparison, 0='', but 1='1'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/), [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/), [Javascript Comparison Operators != vs !== \[closed\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616483/)

Comment: I agree with @Oded - if you can't find an actual duplicate (surely there *must* be one?), the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @outis: I don't think so, that's about using `length`, not `!=` vs. `!==`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the first is about why, which is the same as for this question. In any case, the others are explicitly about strict and type-converting equality.

Comment: @outis: Thank you for finding the true duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use).

Comment: @Oded: Questions with no research effort will be closed, not to mention the half a million duplicates. That I didn't feel like spending my time finding a specific one to closevote on doesn't change that this is obvious a duplicate, and anyone who's been on Stack Overflow for a few months knows that! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var x = false;
console.log(x !== ''); //true
console.log(x != ''); //false
```

In other words, `false` (and other falsy values, like `0`) will coerce to an empty string. The `!==` and `===` operators (strict equality operators) ensure that the things being compared are of the same type.

---

To expand upon why this is the case, you need to head to the spec (linked to by T.J. Crowder in the comments). The section on the "[Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)" tells us the following:

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x)
>   == y.

The section on [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) tells us:

> The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the
>   argument is false.

In the example above, the argument is `false`, so we are now comparing `+0 != ''`. When comparing a number to a string, the following rule is followed:

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the
>   comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Calling [`ToNumber` on an empty string](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) results in `+0`, just as it did for `false`:

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is
>   converted to +0.

Now we are comparing `+0 != +0`, so we enter the "x and y are of the same type" section, which tells us:

> If x is the same Number value as y, return true.

So `+0` is equal to `+0` and since we are using `!=` it returns `false`.

Comment: @ripper234: So you need to know what each does (I recommend reading up - [strict equality](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6) | [loose equality](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)) and then make a decision which to use in any given case. Both have their uses, although one should usually tend toward the strict ones (`===` and `!==`) much of the time.