# How do I check that a Java String is not all whitespaces?

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I want to check that Java String or character array is not just made up of whitespaces, using Java?

This is a very similar question except it's Javascript: 
[[How can I check if string contains characters & whitespace, not just whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031085/check-if-string-contains-characters-whitespaces-not-only-whitespaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031085/check-if-string-contains-characters-whitespaces-not-only-whitespaces)

***EDIT***: I removed the bit about alphanumeric characters, so it makes more sense.

Comment: Be aware that there are many different definitions of whitespace: http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ

Which do you want?  Or then you say "has an alphanumeric character", which is a completely different thing. Please clarify.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion ... not all whitespaces is the key- basically if it has all whitespace characters I want to exclude it, because it has no content.

Comment: With JDK/11 you can [make use of the `String.isBlank`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631090/1746118) API for the same.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Shortest solution I can think of:

```
if (string.trim().length() > 0) ...
```

This only checks for (non) white space. If you want to check for particular character classes, you need to use the mighty `match()` with a regexp such as:

```
if (string.matches(".*\\w.*")) ...
```

...which checks for at least one (ASCII) alphanumeric character.

Comment: FWIW: I would expect the first solution to be considerably faster.

Comment: @Stephen C: Absolutely! But as @Uri pointed out, I'm having to solve two different problems thanks to the ambiguity of the question :) Also, I rarely use `matches()`: for performance, I usually store the `Pattern` in a `final static`. Pays off if the same code runs frequently.

Comment: @Carl - look out, there's one `string == null` coming! - Ouch - NPE - that hurts ;-))

Comment: @Andreas_D: Heh, I got my orders! The OP said he wanted to check a string or char array, he never said anything about nulls! :) \*checks the fine print in the contract\* "`null` is not a string!"

Comment: ".*\\w.*" can be simplified to simply "\\w" to achieve the same result.

Comment: Also, "\\w" only matches a limited subset of non-whitespace characters rather than all non-whitespace since it refers to "word characters" defined as A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore.

Comment: @Rob Raisch, I must object to both of your comments. Second comment first: I explicitly gave "\w" as an example checking for a particular character class, not to solve the original simpler problem. First comment: No, "\\w" will not match a series of word characters preceded, surrounded or followed by other characters, e.g. whitespace. String.matches() matches the entire string, not a subset.

Comment: I used your_string.trim().isEmpty() and did the job for me

Answer (score 66):

I would use the Apache Commons Lang library. It has a class called StringUtils that is useful for all sorts of String operations. For checking if a String is not all whitespaces, you can use the following:

```
StringUtils.isBlank(<your string>)
```

Here is the reference: [StringUtils.isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: I prefer this solution compared to using the chosen answer. This will also check for string == null

Comment: This is now incorrect. `StringUtils.isEmpty` will now return false if you pass in " ".

Answer (score 58):

Slightly shorter than what was mentioned by Carl Smotricz:

```
!string.trim().isEmpty();
```

Comment: You young whippersnappers and your newfangled post-Java-1.6 trickery! Seriously, at least one project in my company still runs on Java 1.4 (sigh).

Comment: Shorter? Yes. Personally, I like the more verbose coding style

Answer (score 23):

```
StringUtils.isBlank(CharSequence)
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Hmm, my compiler doesn't recognize this method in StringUtils.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using **Java 11** or more recent, the new `isBlank` string method will come in handy:

```
!s.isBlank();
```

If you are using **Java 8, 9 or 10**, you could build a simple stream to check that a string is not whitespace only:

```
!s.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace));
```

In addition to not requiring any third-party libraries such as Apache Commons Lang, these solutions have the advantage of handling any white space character, and not just plain `' '` spaces as would a `trim`-based solution suggested in many other answers. You can refer to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-int-) for an exhaustive list of all supported white space types. Note that empty strings are also covered in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

This answer focusses more on the sidenote "*i.e. has at least one alphanumeric character*". Besides that, it doesn't add too much to the other (earlier) solution, except that it doesn't hurt you with NPE in case the String is `null`.

We want `false` if (1) s is `null` or (2) s is empty or (3) s only contains whitechars.

```
public static boolean containsNonWhitespaceChar(String s) {
  return !((s == null) || "".equals(s.trim()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(target.matches("\\S")) 
    // then string contains at least one non-whitespace character
```

Note use of back-slash cap-S, meaning "non-whitespace char"

I'd wager this is the simplest (and perhaps the fastest?) solution.

Comment: Let try: 
`String year="1995"; year.matches("\\S"); will return false`
So this is not correct solution. :|

Comment: Nhat, you are correct though I'm at a loss to explain why. According to the Java docs, String.matches checks to see if a given string matches a regex. A little experimentation shows that this is not entirely accurate, as this function appears to match ONLY if the provided regex matches the ENTIRE string! So, changing the regex above ("\\S") to "^.*\\S.*$" will work as expected, though this behavior isn't correctly documented and appears to diverge substantially from every other implementation of string matching using Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only checking for whitespace and don't care about null then you can use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isWhitespace(String str),

`StringUtils.isWhitespace(String str);`

(Checks if the String contains only whitespace.)

If you also want to check for null(including whitespace) then

```
StringUtils.isBlank(String str);
```

Comment: isBlank(String) is recommended since it handles null validation as well!

Answer (score 4):

With Java-11+, you can make use of the **`String.isBlank`** API to check if the given string is not all made up of whitespace -

```
String str1 = "    ";
System.out.println(str1.isBlank()); // made up of all whitespaces, prints true

String str2 = "    a";
System.out.println(str2.isBlank()); // prints false
```

The javadoc for the same is :

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the string is empty or contains only
 * {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space} codepoints,
 * otherwise {@code false}.
 *
 * @return {@code true} if the string is empty or contains only
 *         {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space} codepoints,
 *         otherwise {@code false}
 *
 * @since 11
 */
public boolean isBlank()
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an performance comparement on openjdk 13, Windows 10. For each of theese texts:

```
"abcd"
"    "
" \r\n\t"
" ab "
" \n\n\r\t   \n\r\t\t\t   \r\n\r\n\r\t \t\t\t\r\n\n"
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  consectetur adipisici elit"
"1234657891234567891324569871234567891326987132654798"
```

executed one of following tests:

```
// trim + empty
input.trim().isEmpty()

// simple match
input.matches("\\S")

// match with precompiled pattern
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\S");
PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()

// java 11's isBlank
input.isBlank()
```

each 10.000.000 times.

The results:

```
METHOD    min   max   note
trim:      18   313   much slower if text not trimmed
match:   1799  2010   
pattern:  571   662   
isBlank:   60   338   faster the earlier hits the first non-whitespace character
```

Quite surprisingly the trim+empty is the fastest. Even if it needs to construct the trimmed text. Still faster then simple for-loop looking for one single non-whitespaced character...

**EDIT:**
The longer text, the more numbers differs. Trim of long text takes longer time than just simple loop. However, the regexs are still the slowest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The trim method should work great for you.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

> Returns a copy of the string, with
>   leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted. If this String object
>   represents an empty character
>   sequence, or the first and last
>   characters of character sequence
>   represented by this String object both
>   have codes greater than '\u0020' (the
>   space character), then a reference to
>   this String object is returned.
>
> Otherwise, if there is no character
>   with a code greater than '\u0020' in
>   the string, then a new String object
>   representing an empty string is
>   created and returned.
>
> Otherwise, let k be the index of the
>   first character in the string whose
>   code is greater than '\u0020', and let
>   m be the index of the last character
>   in the string whose code is greater
>   than '\u0020'. A new String object is
>   created, representing the substring of
>   this string that begins with the
>   character at index k and ends with the
>   character at index m-that is, the
>   result of this.substring(k, m+1).
>
> This method may be used to trim
>   whitespace from the beginning and end
>   of a string; in fact, it trims all
>   ASCII control characters as well.
>
> Returns: A copy of this string with
>   leading and trailing white space
>   removed, or this string if it has no
>   leading or trailing white space.leading or trailing white space.

You could trim and then compare to an empty string or possibly check the length for 0.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *404 | We're sorry, the page does not exist or is no longer available*.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
boolean isWhiteSpaces( String s ) {
    return s != null && s.matches("\\s+");
 }
```

Comment: \\s* will match all strings with or without whitespaces. Perhaps you mean \\s+ ?

Answer (score 0):

trim() and other mentioned regular expression do not work for all types of whitespaces

i.e: Unicode Character 'LINE SEPARATOR'  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Java functions Character.isWhitespace() covers all situations.

That is why already mentioned solution
**StringUtils.isWhitespace( String )** **/or StringUtils.isBlank(String)**
should be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespaceOnly(<your string>)
```

will check :
 - is it null
 - is it only space
 - is it empty string ""

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils&method=isEmptyOrWhitespaceOnly

Comment: Is this from a library? Link to the project. Or built into Java? Indicate the package.

Comment: @BasilBourque i think this is com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespaceOnly

Answer (score 0):

While personally I would be preferring `!str.isBlank()`, as others already suggested (or `str -> !str.isBlank()` as a Predicate), a more modern and efficient version of the `str.trim()` approach mentioned above, would be using `str.strip()` - considering **nulls** as "whitespace":

```
if (str != null && str.strip().length() > 0) {...}
```

For example as Predicate, for use with streams, e. g. in a unit test:

```
@Test
public void anyNonEmptyStrippedTest() {
    String[] strings = null;
    Predicate<String> isNonEmptyStripped = str -> str != null && str.strip().length() > 0;
    assertTrue(Optional.ofNullable(strings).map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).noneMatch(isNonEmptyStripped)).orElse(true));
    strings = new String[] { null, "", " ", "\\n", "\\t", "\\r" };
    assertTrue(Optional.ofNullable(strings).map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).anyMatch(isNonEmptyStripped)).orElse(true));
    strings = new String[] { null, "", " ", "\\n", "\\t", "\\r", "test" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isStringBlank(final CharSequence cs) {
        int strLen;
        if (cs == null || (strLen = cs.length()) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(cs.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```