# Replace empty, null and whitespace-only fields with new value in one statement

Tags: java, talend

I have a Java expression that's I'm using in Talend Open Studio's tMap component, trying to clean up fields that are null, empty and consist of *only* white spaces

I tried this statement but it hasn't remove the white spaces:

`(myTable.myField == null || StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).length() > 0 || myTable.myField.isEmpty()) ? "Not Set" : myTable.myField`

The nulls and empty fields are working, but I have a field with just a white space in it and this isn't getting rid of it

I'd like to remove all spaces from , not just leading/trailing

I borrowed the whitespace statement from here: [How do I check that a Java String is not all whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247067/how-to-check-that-java-string-is-not-all-whitespaces)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string dupe, please do some research before asking a question.

Comment: Hi, does the question you have linked to also deal with null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have made a typo
just change

```
(myTable.myField == null || StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).length() > 0 || myTable.myField.isEmpty()) ? "Not Set" : myTable.myField
```

to

```
(myTable.myField == null || StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).length() == 0 || myTable.myField.isEmpty()) ? "Not Set" : myTable.myField
```

or try `StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).equals("")` either, or `StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).isEmpty()` check [this](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=95926)

Comment: Thank You; I ended up not needing the third case, since I think StringHandling.TRIM(myTable.myField).length()==0 should also catch the empty strings

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility method that I use:

```
public static boolean isNullOrWhiteSpace(final CharSequence value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    final int length = value.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The method returns `true` if the value is `null`, empty, or consists only of whitespace.  For your use case, you could write:

```
String result = isNullOrWhiteSpace(myTable.myField) ? "Not Set"
                                                    : myTable.myField;
```

Unlike solutions that use `trim()`, this will not generate any garbage.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind importing a jar, [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) can solve it.

Otherwise, then String itself has a trim() method, which will help you:

```
public class ReplaceEmpty {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] ss = { "", "   ", null , "GOOD String"};
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ReplaceEmpty.process(ss[i]));
        }
    }

    public static String process(String s) {
        return (s == null || s.trim().equals("")) ? "REPLACEMENT" : s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to replace all the spaces in your string with the empty string.

```
myTable.myField = myTable.myField.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

For example this:

```
String test = "t eff  aa d d ";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Will print out `teffaadd`

Comment: Hi, this deals with the blank spaces, but what about nulls and empty fields? I'd like to give treat them all alike and give them a default value like "invalid" or "not set"