# How to know if the string variabel contains only space in java?

Tags: java, string, space

I have a variable that's a string and I want to replace the string with "null" if the variable contains only a space or multiple spaces. How can I do it?

Comment: `String.isBlank()` will tell you if it's only a space or `""`

Comment: `String.isBlank()` is an apache util method and not part of JDK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check that a Java String is not all whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247067/how-do-i-check-that-a-java-string-is-not-all-whitespaces)

Answer (score 6):

Try the followoing :

```
 if(str.trim().isEmpty()){
         str = null;
 }
```

Comment: He said 'space', not 'whitespace'. `trim()` operates on whitespace. Subtle difference that may be important to him.

Comment: @Andy Brown : I don't think he wants a `\t` only string.

Comment: @AndyBrown could you give me the link or explanation here what are the difference between those 2 things in programming?)

Comment: I also understand the question the way that he doesn't want empty strings. This also includes all other whitespace characters, too.

Comment: @Donvino you could google it. Basically, space is the 32 ascii char ' ', whitespaces are tab, new line, etc..

Comment: @DeiAndrei yep, did it, thanks for the brief answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way you could do it:

```
    String spaces = "   -- - -";
    if (spaces.matches("[ -]*")) {
        System.out.println("Only spaces and/or - or empty");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not only spaces");
    }
```

Comment: is it work if there only one space or multiple spaces?

Comment: it works for multiple spaces but not for whitespaces (e.g. tab, newline)

Comment: use `spaces.matches("[ ]+")` to identify a string that is entirely composed of one or more spaces.

Comment: it works, now i have one more problem, if in my string variabel contains single/multiple of space and single/multiple of - character, ex:(  -   ), i want to replace with "null".

Comment: @Muhammad just replace the [ ] regex with [ -]. Note that + means 1 ore more, * stands for 0 or more

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your variable is `String var`

Then,

```
if(var.replace(" ", "").equals("")) {
    var = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all you can implement it your self for example by using a regular expression which is very simple.

The Java Regex definition defines "/s" as the pattern for all whitespace characters. So a String matching "/s+" is empty or only includes whitespaces.

Here is an example:

```
public boolean isEmpty(String value) {
  return value.matches("/s*");
}
```

But normaly it isn't a good idea to do this by your self. It is a so common pattern that it is implemented in a lot of libraries already.
My best practice in nearly all java apps I've written is to use the apache commons lang library. Which includes the StringUtils class.
All methods in this class are nullsave and keep an eye on all possible scenarios about what is for example an empty string.

So with apache commons it is:

```
StringUtils.isBlank(value);
```

Have a look here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html

Comment: Or `.matches("\\s*");`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if(yourstring.replace(" ","").length()==0) {
    yourstring = null;
}
```

Doesn't need regexes so should be a little more efficient than solutions that do.

Comment: then when my string variable contains not only space?

Comment: Hey! That's pretty much what I said! :D