# Java String[] array = line.split(" ") where line is just whitespace

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am writing a program where I am reading from a file, and the separator for my file data is a blank line, just whitespace, and I want to skip it whenever I get to it. My expression for reading from the file is String[] array = f.nextLine(" "). I tried putting conditions after this line, something like if(array.length == 0) or if (array == null), but it doesn't seem to get into these.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, [edit] your question to include the code relevant to your question (a [mcve] would be even better).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check that a Java String is not all whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247067/how-do-i-check-that-a-java-string-is-not-all-whitespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For white space first trim the line:

```
line.trim();
```

And then check if it's null:

```
if (line.equals(""));
```

Then split it by using:

```
String[] array = line.split (" ");
```

This will help!