# how to check if the variable is null?

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I know this doesnt work but how can I know if the user added even one char?

```
public class Program
import java.util.Scanner;
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String b = a.nextLine();

//I know this doesnt work but how can I know if the user added even one char?
    if (b!=null){
    System.out.println(b);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can check [String.length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) ... and [String.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) is equivalent to checking length for 0.

Comment: `b.isEmpty()`. `nextLine()` never returns null.

Comment: Mind that Whitespaces count for length. So if you actually want to check for "Non-Whitespace characters" then there is a little more effort. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247081/982149

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `.equals("")` or `.isEmpty()`

check [check if the variable is null](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70414/close-scanner-if-no-input)

Comment: Why you'd even suggest `equals("")` when `String` has `isEmpty()` is beyond me.

Comment: because you can use `equals("")` also as it is from parent calss `Object`  but you are right , better to use `isEmpty()` because ,see The main benefit of `"".equals()` is you don't need the null check (equals will check its argument and return false if it's null), which you seem to not care about. If you're not worried about `b` being null (or are otherwise checking for it), I would definitely use `.isEmpty()`; it shows exactly what you're checking, you care whether or not `b` is empty, not whether it equals the empty string

Comment: Your answer advocates `.equals("")` not `"".equals(s)`. It also did not include the advantages of using `"".equals(s)`. Are you expecting this to come naturally to the readers who read your answer but not the comments? I still stand by that this is a bad answer.

Comment: i am not telling you the advantages am telling you how many ways we can check..so `.equals()` is also one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
if (!b.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: The `b != null` is redundant.