# Making the equivalent of Rails `present?` in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Rails we can `.present?` to check if a string is not-`nil` and contains something other than white-space or an empty string:

```
"".present?       # => false
"     ".present?  # => false
nil.present?      # => false
"hello".present?  # => true
```

I would like similar functionality in Javascript, without having to write a function for it like `function string_present?(str) { ... }`

Is this something I can do with Javascript out-of-the-box or by adding to the `String`'s prototype?

I did this:

```
String.prototype.present = function()
{
    if(this.length > 0) {
      return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But, how would I make this work:

```
var x = null; x.present

var y; y.present
```

Comment: If you didn't have the "could also be only whitespace" requirement, then you could simply use the string variable in any boolean statement (e.g. `if (myStr) {...}`), since `null`, `undefined`, and `''` are falsey values in JavaScript.

Comment: On further reflection, I don't think you're going to get something as "nice looking" as `.present?`, since you cannot do `null.property` in JavaScript. BradM has probably the best solution to this.

Comment: Have a look at [How can I check if string contains characters & whitespace, not just whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031085/how-can-i-check-if-string-contains-characters-whitespace-not-just-whitespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.prototype.present = function() {
    return this && this.trim() !== '';
};
```

If the value can be `null`, you can't use the prototype approach to test, you can use a function.

```
function isPresent(string) {
    return typeof string === 'string' && string.trim() !== '';
}
```

Comment: How would you call this on a variable with the value `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The best is if statement or first one approach, ie. string_present() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can double invert variable:

```
> var a = "";
undefined
> !a
true
> !!a
false
> var a = null;
undefined
> !!a
false
> var a = " ";
> !!a.trim();
false
```

And than:

```
if (!!a && !!a.trim()) {
  true
}else{
  false
}
```

Comment: Fails for the case `a = "    "; !!a` =>  `true` but wanted is `false`