# Enable button on entering a character other than space in angular2

Tags: angular, textarea

I have a comment section which is in form of text area and I want to enable a another button if user start typing some character(except space) into the textarea. How can I do that in angular2?

I already have it working but my problem is that the button gets enabled even if the user enter 'space' in text area. How can I correct this behavior so that only when user writes something the button gets enabled?

in html:

```
<textarea id="comments"
   class="comments-text"
   [(ngModel)]="text"
   (ngModelChange)="onAddComment($event)"
   name="text"></textarea>

<button [disabled]="EnableButton()">
```

in component:

```
 public onAddComment(event: string): void {
    this.passedString = event;
    }

 public EnableButton(): void {
    return !!this.passedString;
}
```

Comment: Can v see your code?

Comment: just added the code, thanks for your help

Comment: and the code for button elem is..

Comment: updated. this is working except that I want if only spaces entered the button doesn't get enabled. how  can I do that?

Comment: See my answer for that.

Comment: What do you mean by space? only spaces or atleast one space?

Comment: I want button to be disable if the only thing that is entered into textarea is space and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttonIsDisabled:boolean=true;
public onAddComment(event: string): void {
   this.buttonIsDisabled=true;
   let passedString = event;
   if (/\S/.test(passedString)) {
       // string is not empty and not just whitespace
       // activate button
       this.buttonIsDisabled=false;
   }
}
```

`<button [disabled]="buttonIsDisabled">`

This should do the trick. See
[How can I check if string contains characters & whitespace, not just whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031085/how-can-i-check-if-string-contains-characters-whitespace-not-just-whitespace)

Comment: sorry for dumb question, what is /\S/ ?

Comment: That's a regular expression: \S: "Matches a single character other than white space." See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can check with every `textarea` value change, if it contains any other sign than a whitespace.

```js
onAddComment() {
  if (this.text.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
    this.check = true;
  } else {
    this.check = false;
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yj6zK4SlziUcygDpqPRd?p=preview)**

Comment: this will not work if there is sentence and it between there is space. I just want to disable only if all string is space

Comment: @AlreadyLost I got it. It has to be disabled if there are only whitespaces in the content. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

trim() can be used to remove spaces.