# Javascript: How to check if a string is empty?

Tags: javascript, string

I know this is really basic, but I am new to javascript and can't find an answer anywhere.

How can I check if a string is empty?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: does whitespace count as empty? if so, you'll likely want a regex to test it.

Comment: Came here to add that some people should actually be checking for `isBlank`  which would be `variable.trim() === ''`

Comment: Trimming a string always make sense

if(title.trim().length === 0) { //code}

Answer (score 172):

I check length.

```
if (str.length == 0) {
}
```

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic but `if (!str || str.length === 0)` would be preferable. (Note the 3 equals signs.) +1 to @Dustin though.

Comment: If you add blank spaces to your string, `length` counts the blank spaces, so with `length` we can't determine whether a string is empty or not.

Comment: @evolquez space is not same as empty,  so is the case with null.  space is a character so it can't be treated as `""`. OP is asking about empty string and I think this solution works well.

Comment: @ChrisNash Why would you need `===` instead of `==` in this specific case? Is it possible for `str.length` to return something other than a numeric value that might evaluate to `falsy`?

Comment: @buffer This explains it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: @ChrisNash I understand why `===` is better in general, but for this specific case, I can't find a reason where `str.length` would be zero due to type conversion. Are you using it as a convention or is there an example where you can get unexpected results?

Comment: var str = "         "; now how you will check ????

Comment: Don't forget to trim `if (!str || str.trim().length === 0)`

Comment: @intrepidis not pedantic at all, that's core, foundational js. You just saved one some unnecessary aggravation. This answer as it stands is small disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: so why `.length == 0` is better than `=== ""` ??? I need an answer.

Answer (score 60):

If you want to know if it's an empty string use === instead of ==.

```
if(variable === "") {
}
```

This is because === will only return true if the values on both sides are of the same type, in this case a string.

for example:
(false == "")  will return true, and (false === "") will return false.

Answer (score 13):

This should work:

```
if (variable === "") {

}
```

Answer (score 12):

But for a better check:

```
if(str === null || str === '')
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: Actually I was going to edit this before it got closed:

    if(!str || str == "")
    {
        //enter code here
    }

There are many ways to do this, but a String is not necessarily null if it has "" in it. Empty is **not** null.

Comment: where did you learn that a null variable has a length of 0 in JS?  What is the source where you found this info?

Comment: What if str is undefined? If you're checking falsiness, your best bet is `if (!str)`. But if you're checking for empty string, as per the question, I think nxt's is the best. The accepted answer should be using ===, and if str is null/undefined, you get your classic Uncaught ReferenceError.

Comment: This answer is miscorrect because the condition gonna be truthy even if variable `str` is `null`, while `null` is an `object` type, not `string`.

Answer (score -12):

```
if (value == "") {
  // it is empty
}
```

Comment: If value is really a string, then this is correct, but it will also return true, if value = false or 0 or null. use === instead.

Comment: @Residuum: The question reads “How to check if a string is empty?”

Comment: @Gumbo: An answer that works under all circumstances is in my opinion better than an answer that provides the bare minimum, so I agree with Residuum. Things like that are especially important to point out for a beginner.

Comment: @Gumbo: As the question suggests, the questioner is not experienced in Javascript. And as Javascript is not a strongly typed language, it is a common source of error to not explicitly check for type as well. Been there, done that.