# How to write OR in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do you write `OR` in Javascript?

Example :

```
if ( age **or** name == null ){
    do something
}
```

Comment: What language allows you to do `(age or name == null)`?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place to learn the very basic syntax of a language.  Try a reference book or web site.

Comment: @Quentin my bad I just noticed it

Comment: @drderp there are a few languages out there that allow or as a keyword. Fortran, for example.

Comment: @drderp COBOL has expression syntax kind-of like that.

Comment: @drderp: Many languages allow you to write exactly that, making a "truthy/falsy" determination about the value of age.

Comment: @LarryLustig I don't think that was the intent, though.

Comment: @drderp : PHP allows you to use OR and AND operators

Comment: @DaveNewton: I agree, but the statement that no language will let you write that syntax is very, very misleading.

Comment: @LarryLustig I was not trying to imply that no language would let you do that; you can do it, you just have to be sure of the results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use:

```
if ( age == null || name == null ){    
    // do something    
}
```

Although, if you're simply testing to see if the variables have a value (and so are 'falsey' rather than equal to `null`) you could use instead:

```
if ( !age || !name ){    
    // do something    
}
```

References:

- [Logical operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 10):

```
if (age == null || name == null) {

}
```

Note: You may want to see this thread, [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript), for information on null/undefined variables in JS.

Comment: `===` would be a smidge better

Comment: Don´t just check for a null variable, it could be undefined also. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript

Comment: @pdjota `undefined == null` is true; you only need to differentiate if you're using `===` or specifically care about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the way that or associates.  `(age or name == null)` will actually be `((age or name) == null)`, which is not what you want to say.  You want `((age == null) or (name == null))`.  When in doubt, insert parentheses.  If you put in parentheses and evaluated, you would have seen that the situations became something like `(true == null)` and `(false == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have **OR** operator in **JavaScript,** we use `||` instead, in your case do...:

```
if (age || name == null) {
  //do something
}
```