# Refer to a href inside div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to do ajax call on window load and use a url which is inside div#links

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
$(window).load(function() {


    baseUrl =  $("#links a").attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "",
        success: function(data) {

            // from here not important
```

HTML:

```
<div id="links"></div>
```

Links are created dynamicly:

```
$('<a href="' + text + lnk + '">' + text + lnk + '</a>')
    .appendTo($('#links'));
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you post some relevant HTML, too?

Comment: I allready mentioned the relevant HTML which is div#links......

Comment: What is the not working part?

Comment: @xdazz The not working part is that the call is not made because the url is not defined

Comment: Then we need to see your html :) Either there is no `a` inside your links div, it doesn't have a href attribute set correctly or your div doesn't have the correct id.

Comment: @Jeroen Moons Okay.......<div id="links"></div> Links are created dynamicly  $('<a href="' + text + lnk + '">' + text + lnk + '</a>').appendTo($('#links'));

Comment: Do you have attribute href in the anchor tag?

Comment: Does the `href`resolve to an actual URL?

Comment: @Youss if that's all your html no wonder it won't work :) What does the a tag look like

Comment: @David Thomas Okay this one I should have mentioned...The url is created dynamicly on document ready, that why I use window load

Comment: @Jeroen Moons I updated my previous answer

Comment: I added your comment to the question, it's important info. Did you check with firebug or the like wether your links are built correctly?

Comment: @Jeroen Moons I dont know how to but the links are okay, Just look at the example http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/142/

Comment: Ahhh you have an example, should've mentioned that :) Seems to work here, it loads content from the url

Comment: Its the second code (window load) which doesn't work (ps I didn't mentioned all that other stuff because I didn't think it whas important..(I whas wrong)

Comment: Ok I've checked it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just not waiting for your `#links` div to be filled with content.

The first ajax call fills the links div with its content. On window.load your ajax call hasn't finished yet but you try to access these links already.

You need to execute that code when the first ajax call's success handler is fired. Now the links div doesn't contain anything yet so trying to get an `a`tag's href from an `a`tag that isn't there yet fails.

Answer (score 3):

*updated*

it should be

```
var baseUrl = ...
```

(for proper scoping)

but that's not the real problem... looks like (for a start)
at the the line

```
$foop = $('<form>' + data.responseText + '</form>');
```

data.responseText is an entire html document  (which this line of code then attempts to wrap with a form element) - so that'll be a major source of issues....

Comment: Please look at my code http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/142/  It should work, but it doesn't...

Comment: Without the `var` wouldn't it just create a global variable?

Comment: I don't think its the var that is causing problems

Comment: I googled and replaced data.responseText with innerHTML.responseText Doesn't work...(sadly that's all I can think of)

Comment: @David Thomas - possibly, depending on your javascript engine - but that's certainly not the standard as far as I know... I believe that if a variable is undeclared, any reference to it will generate an error (except when using the typeof function) - see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript

Comment: @Youss I'm afraid you'll probably need to create a question that is more specific ... Stack Overflow is not about doing other people's work for them - sorry

Comment: I've found the problem, see my answer.

Comment: @Nathan var deadline = thisQuestion :)