# JavaScript null check

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, null-check

I've come across the following code:

```
function test(data) {
    if (data != null && data !== undefined) {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

I'm somewhat new to JavaScript, but, from other questions I've been reading here, I'm under the impression that this code does not make much sense.

---

<del>In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2559513/2088822) states that</del>

> <del>You'll get an error if you access an undefined variable in any context other than `typeof`.</del>

**Update:** The (quote of the) answer above may be misleading. It should say *«an undeclared variable»*, instead of *«an undefined variable»*.

As I found out, in the answers by [*Ryan ♦*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16672768/2088822), [*maerics*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16673024/2088822), and [*nwellnhof*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674810/2088822), even when no arguments are provided to a function, its variables for the arguments are always declared. This fact also proves wrong the first item in the list below.

---

From my understanding, the following scenarios may be experienced:

- <del>The function was called with no arguments, thus making `data` an undefined variable, and raising an error on `data != null`.</del>
- The function was called specifically with `null` (or `undefined`), as its argument, in which case `data != null` already protects the inner code, rendering `&& data !== undefined` useless.
- The function was called with a non-null argument, in which case it will trivially pass both `data != null` **and** `data !== undefined`.

**Q: Is my understanding correct?**

---

I've tried the following, in Firefox's console:

```
--
[15:31:31.057] false != null
[15:31:31.061] true
--
[15:31:37.985] false !== undefined
[15:31:37.989] true
--
[15:32:59.934] null != null
[15:32:59.937] false
--
[15:33:05.221] undefined != null
[15:33:05.225] false
--
[15:35:12.231] "" != null
[15:35:12.235] true
--
[15:35:19.214] "" !== undefined
[15:35:19.218] true
```

I can't figure out a case where the `data !== undefined` **after** `data != null` might be of any use.

Comment: Just use `if (data)`. It's mnemonic Javascript way to check if `data` variable evaluates to true. `undefined`, `null`, false, 0, empty string, empty array and (?)object with no properties evaluates to false, the rest is true.

Comment: @J0HN - Using `if(data)` would mean that he can't pass `false` or `0` as values for `data`.

Comment: @J0HN Also, the same answer I mention also states that: `if(typeof someUndefVar == whatever) -- works`, and `if(someUnderVar) -- error`.

Comment: It's probably supposed to be `data !== null && data !== undefined`, which is equivalent to `data != null` which is equivalent to `data != undefined`. The former form tends to be favored as it's more explicit about the conditions, whereas it'd be easy to overlook that both `null` and `undefined` are being checked with the later two conditions.

Comment: By the way, explicit tests for `undefined` are IMO a code smell.  It's not a protected keyword like `null`, it's a variable that happens to be undefined.  This is completely valid and is going to break your code: `undefined = 1`

Comment: @Izkata I've read here, on another occasion, that one should not mess up too much with `undefined`, as it can actually be *defined*, as you point out. Since then, I try to avoid mentioning `undefined` anywhere in my code, and, when needed, I just go for `typeof`, or `== null`.

Comment: Minor point of annoyance: "It's mnemonic Javascript," should be, "It's idiomatic Javascript."

Comment: @J0HN `Boolean({})` and `Boolean([])` are true.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

An “undefined variable” is different from the value `undefined`.

An undefined variable:

```
var a;
alert(b); // ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

A variable with the value `undefined`:

```
var a;
alert(a); // Alerts “undefined”
```

When a function takes an argument, that argument is always declared even if its value is `undefined`, and so there won’t be any error. You are right about `!= null` followed by `!== undefined` being useless, though.

Comment: `data !== null && data !== undefined` would make sense, though.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yep, so it might actually be a typo. But you never know… :D

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks for the clarification. Also, I do not think it's a typo. I've run a *find-and-count* in the whole script, and it found 10 occurrences, so... I guess the author also needs clarification on this.

Comment: Scratch my comment above: actually, `data != null` would check for both `null` and `undefined` (but, interestingly, just for `null` and `undefined`, and not the other falsy values).

Answer (score 96):

In JavaScript, `null` is a special singleton object which is helpful for signaling "no value".  You can test for it by comparison and, as usual in JavaScript, it's a good practice to use the `===` operator to avoid confusing type coercion:

```
var a = null;
alert(a === null); // true
```

As @rynah mentions, "undefined" is a bit confusing in JavaScript.  However, it's always safe to test if the `typeof(x)` is the string "undefined", even if "x" is not a declared variable:

```javascript
alert(typeof(x) === 'undefined'); // true
```

Also, variables can have the "undefined value" if they are not initialized:

```javascript
var y;
alert(typeof(y) === 'undefined'); // true
```

Putting it all together, your check should look like this:

```javascript
if ((typeof(data) !== 'undefined') && (data !== null)) {
  // ...
```

However, since the variable "data" is always defined since it is a formal function parameter, using the "typeof" operator is unnecessary and you can safely compare directly with the "undefined value".

```javascript
function(data) {
  if ((data !== undefined) && (data !== null)) {
    // ...
```

This snippet amounts to saying "if the function was called with an argument which is defined and is not null..."

Comment: Why *should* it look like that, though? `!= null` will be true for all values except `null` and `undefined`, and we’re sure that this variable is declared. `typeof` in other situations can even be dangerous — what if you mistype the variable name? That can go undetected for a long time because there’s no error.

Comment: @maerics So, if I followed your answer correctly, in a null check like the above scenario, you would not use `!=` at all, only strict comparison, `!==`?

Comment: @rynah: I don't presume to know enough about OP's overall solution to know if a null test is appropriate or not but I did edit to mention the fact that using "typeof" is unnecessary.

Comment: @afsantos: in reality I don't think that many (any?) values will convert to null; however, it's a best practice to use strict comparison (`===`) unless you really know what you're doing and want comparison after conversion (`==`).

Comment: @maerics Sure, I agree on that. Just as extra clarification, I did run more tests in the console. The only values that seem to convert to null are `undefined` and `null` itself. Running `undefined == null` yields `true`.

Comment: +1 entirely for `typeof(data) !== "undefined"`, which doesn't fall into the `undefined = 1` trap

Comment: @Izkata: That trap only applies if you use Internet Explorer 8 or earlier for development, use Yoda conditionals, and use loose equality all the time. That’s a rare combination.

Comment: @rynah We still have to support IE6 for our clients, this became known as a trap because at one time it was abused in a JS library, and Safari on the iPad throws javascript exceptions in certain situations relating to it not being a keyword: `undefined is undefined`.  So all in all, I still say, don't rely on it.

Comment: @Izkata: Drop any library that attempts to redefine `undefined`. Also, Safari on the iPad will do that under no circumstances. You can’t even `delete window.undefined`.

Answer (score 23):

In your case use `data==null` (which is true ONLY for null and undefined - on second picture focus on rows/columns null-undefined)

```js
function test(data) {
    if (data != null) {
        console.log('Data: ', data);
    }
}

test();          // the data=undefined
test(null);      // the data=null
test(undefined); // the data=undefined

test(0); 
test(false); 
test('something');
```

Here you have all ([src](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)):

**if**

[image]

**==** (its negation **!=**)

[image]

**===** (its negation **!==**)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Q:** The function was called with no arguments, thus making data an undefined variable, and raising an error on data != null.

**A:** Yes, `data` will be set to undefined. See [section 10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.5) of the spec. But accessing an undefined value does not raise an error. You're probably confusing this with accessing an undeclared variable in strict mode which does raise an error.

**Q:** The function was called specifically with null (or undefined), as its argument, in which case data != null already protects the inner code, rendering && data !== undefined useless.

**Q:** The function was called with a non-null argument, in which case it will trivially pass both data != null and data !== undefined.

**A:** Correct. Note that the following tests are equivalent:

```
data != null
data != undefined
data !== null && data !== undefined
```

See [section 11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) and [section 11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6) of the spec.

Comment: I wasn't confusing with undeclared variables, I really didn't know how it worked when no arguments were provided. I was convinced that `data` would not exist at all, instead of being set to `undefined`. I appreciate the clarification, and those references helped me understand in better detail how both equalities work.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof foo === "undefined"` is different from `foo === undefined`, never confuse them. `typeof foo === "undefined"` is what you really need. Also, use `!==` in place of `!=`

So the statement can be written as

```
function (data) {
  if (typeof data !== "undefined" && data !== null) {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can not use `foo === undefined` for undeclared variables.

```
var t1;

if(typeof t1 === "undefined")
{
  alert("cp1");
}

if(t1 === undefined)
{
  alert("cp2");
}

if(typeof t2 === "undefined")
{
  alert("cp3");
}

if(t2 === undefined) // fails as t2 is never declared
{
  alert("cp4");
}
```

Comment: Okay, but the variable is declared in this case, so what’s the issue?

Comment: Personally, I find `foo === undefined` dangerous to use. It makes your code fails for the same condition you were trying to prevent.

Comment: I’m talking about the argument to the function in question. See also [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672743/javascript-null-check/16672768?noredirect=1#comment23990069_16673024).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted‽  The very first sentence is a correct and _important_ distinction!

Comment: @Izkata: because there is no explanation for the initial statement. `foo === undefined` is perfectly acceptable in the OP's situation (assuming `undefined` has not been overridden). The answer also fails to explain *why* `!==` should be used in place of `!=`.

Answer (score 3):

I think, testing variables for values you do not expect is not a good idea in general. Because the test as your you can consider as writing a blacklist of forbidden values. But what if you forget to list all the forbidden values? Someone, even you, can crack your code with passing an unexpected value. So a more appropriate approach is something like whitelisting - testing variables only for the expected values, not unexpected. For example, if you expect the data value to be a string, instead of this:

```
function (data) {
  if (data != null && data !== undefined) {
    // some code here
    // but what if data === false?
    // or data === '' - empty string?
  }
}
```

do something like this:

```
function (data) {
  if (typeof data === 'string' && data.length) {
    // consume string here, it is here for sure
    // cleaner, it is obvious what type you expect
    // safer, less error prone due to implicit coercion
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do your test is :

```
function (data) {
    if (data) { // check if null, undefined, empty ...
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this test context-dependent? I mean, if the expected type for `data` is a string, this test returns false on empty strings, which may, or may not, be appropriate (the function might want to deal with the empty string in some way).

Comment: Except that if "data" has the value `""` or `0` or `NaN` (or others) the "if" block will be skipped; which may or may not be OP's intent.

Comment: Sorry @afsantos, I didn't saw your comment, if you want to get false when data is undefined, null ... except when date is an empty, you'll need to create an other *var toTest = data;* with an other test after the first one like : *if(toTest=="") { // some code here }*

Answer (score -5):

```
var a;
alert(a); //Value is undefined

var b = "Volvo"; 
alert(b); //Value is Volvo

var c = null;
alert(c); //Value is null
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: This doesn’t really _check_ for `null`.