# Performing arithmetic operations on nullable types in react with a prior check for null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a props of folllowing form :

```
type Props = {
 row = ?number
};
```

When I try to do

```
if (row === null) {
      return null;
    }
const percent = Math.round((row * 100)/20);
```

I get error that

> operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number

If I do

```
type Props = {
 row = number
};
```

error goes away.
Any suggestions on what to do :)

Comment: I am getting error `const percent = Math.round((row * 100)/20);` for this line

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16673024/2065611

Comment: `const percent = row ? Math.round((row * 100)/20) : null;` Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is not in a function.
Here even if your row is null you are executing your second statement. Put it in else part. And you also need to return percent.

Like this-

```
if (row === null) {
  return null;
}

else {
  const percent = Math.round((row * 100)/20);
  return percent;
}
```