# If statement checking not null is being ignored

Tags: javascript

Below is a portion of code I'm using to get the href or src of an image of known class or id. The console.log() returns null, even though it is in an if statement checking that the attribute later used isn't null.
Of course, trying to get href or src of null doesn't end well.

```
for(var i = 0 ; (i < sitelist[site].img_id.length) && (img === undefined) ; i++)
{
    if(document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]) !== undefined)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]) !== null)
        {
            console.log(document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]));
            if(document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]).href !== undefined)
            {
                img =   document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]).href;
            }
            if(document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]).src !== undefined)
            {
                img =   document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]).src;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a specific way of checking if something is null, or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: There is no null in javascript

Comment: @PrasathK [yes there is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/801032/447356). Maybe not the same like in languages such as C or C# but `null` is an object thus it exists.

Comment: Of course there is null in js, you're completely wrong! http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp?output=print

Comment: Better reference, in my opinion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: ekhm ... what about: var x = null; if(x === null) alert('nulls exists!'); ?

Comment: @Andrew—best reference is [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.1).

Comment: Agreed @RobG, but less accessible.

Comment: @Andrew—heaven forbid a programmer should learn to read the language specification. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, [edit: in web development] many don't =)

Comment: @Andrew Then use the more readable version: http://es5.github.io/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `null` and `undefined` tests are correct, though longer than needed.

Your actual issue is that you're testing for `.img_id[i]`, but then using `.img_class[i]`.

Here's a more concise version of your existing code.

```
for(var i = 0 ; (i < sitelist[site].img_id.length) && (img === undefined) ; i++) { 

// Here you're testing the `img_id[i]`
    var img_id = document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]);

    if(img_id != null) {

// Here you're trying to use a different element
        var img_clss = document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_class[i]);
        console.log(img_clss);

        if(img_clss.href !== undefined) {
            img =   img_clss.href;
        }
        if(img_clss.src !== undefined) {
            img = img_clss.src;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless the values are the same, testing for one isn't going to tell you if a different one exists.

I don't know what the intent is, but perhaps you just need to change the element inside the `if`.

```
for(var i = 0 ; (i < sitelist[site].img_id.length) && (img === undefined) ; i++) { 
    // Here you're testing the `img_id[i]`
    var img_id = document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]);

    if(img_id != null) {
        // Now we're using the same element that we tested!
        console.log(img_id);

        if(img_id.href !== undefined) {
            img = img_id.href;
        }
        if(img_id.src !== undefined) {
            img = img_id.src;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The real problem was truly that I was checking img_id then using img_class. Shame on me.
I will ameliorate its readability and compactness though.

Answer (score 2):

You can just try the below code.

Replace

```
if (document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]) !== undefined) {
    if (document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]) !== null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

with

```
if (document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i])) {
    // process here
}
```

You are checking null and undefined continuously in next statement. You can just try with element only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript

Comment: The problem wasn't on the structure but on the variables used. The test was on img_id and img_class was used.
Your answer is perfectly true, but the problem wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
   id[i]) !== undefined
```

with

```
   id[i]) != undefined
```

in all statements

Comment: @CaramelTruffle yes you need to change in all  places

Comment: @CaramelTruffle did you tried this by replacing in alla places

Comment: I will remember it, thanks. The source of the problem seems to be somewhere else though.
Edit: And yes, I replaced all !== by !=

Answer (score 1):

To test if the element is found, simply use

```
var elem = document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i]);
if (elem) {
   // proceed from there
```

Note that I also declared a variable. Repeating your `document.getElementById(sitelist[site].img_id[i])` makes your code hard to read (and thus debug and maintain).

Comment: I agree for the readability part, but isn't it bad concerning the time required to execute the code?

Comment: @CaramelTruffle On the contrary : it avoids fetching the element more than once.

Comment: I will remember it and start using it then. Thanks.