# Typescript doesn't know what FormData is

Tags: javascript, typescript

When trying to use `window.FormData` I get the following error:

```
The name 'FormData' does not exist in the current scope
```

The same happens to FileReader

Comment: It should, as there's an [issue](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/720) about it, fixed already. What version of TypeScript is used?

Comment: Weird. Ok, what if you use `FormData` without `window` prefix?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: Ah, so it does recognize FormData, but now how can I check if the browser supports it? Im using code that checks for window.FormData to search for browser support.

Answer (score 16):

add `dom` to the `lib` array in the `tsconfig.json` of your project.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"], // add `dom` to the array
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check a feature exists using:

```
if (window.FormData) {
    alert('Yes');
}
```

This relies on falsey checks - if you want to be explicit, use.

```
if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {
    alert('Yes');
}
```

Comment: Falsey checks are bad for undefined since it throws an exception. Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/2MJ8j/ The explicit one is fine :)

Comment: I see that mate, but the falsey example is *wrong* "Undefined variables , like 'foo'. You'll get an error if you access an undefined variable in any context other than typeof." http://stackoverflow.com/a/2559513/390330

Comment: you can use `if (window.FormData)` if you want the falsey check. `if (FormData)` is a straight up exception and not a functioning piece of code. Made the edit if thats okay :)