# Undefined or null for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, null, undefined

When I write watch handling functions I check newVal param on `undefined` and `null`. Why does AngularJS have such a behavior, but doesn't have particular utility method? So there is `angular.isUndefined` but not `angular.isUndefinedOrNull`. It isn't hard to implement that by hand but how extend angular to have that function in each controller? Tnx.

**Edit**:

The example:

```
$scope.$watch("model", function(newVal) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(newVal) || newVal == null) return;
    // do somethings with newVal
}
```

Is it common accepted practice to handle such a way?

**Edit 2**:

The JSFiddle example (http://jsfiddle.net/ubA9r/):

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
      <select ng-model="model" ng-options="m for m in models">
          <option value="" class="ng-binding">Choose model</option>
      </select>
      {{model}}
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module("App", []);

var MainCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.models = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
    $scope.$watch("model", function(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
    });
};
```

Comment: You could switch to coffeescript. There is a questionmark postifix operator that does that.

Comment: could you please give the real case when you need such functionality?

Comment: Why not [lose the undefined check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992131/188246) and just check `newVal == null`?

Comment: Because (newVal === null) returns false if newVal is undefined.

Comment: Yes, `newVal === null` will be false, but `newVal == null` will be true. David is correct.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can always add it exactly for your application

```
angular.isUndefinedOrNull = function(val) {
    return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null 
}
```

Comment: I know that isn't always good to extend js libraries such a way but it looks very close to my searching. Actually, I am more interested in why I stuck in it. Is it a standard practice to handle undefined and null in watch handlers?

Comment: Well, IMHO, in good-structured application there should not be such cases.

Comment: got it, thx. But I still think that 'null' is a result of correct selection and it should be distinguished from 'undefined'.

Comment: @STEVER why would 'null' be bad in a well-structured application?  If, for example, a variable should only be filled with user data when the user is logged in, null is the proper value before login and after logout.

Answer (score 17):

My suggestion to you is to write your own utility service.  You can include the service in each controller or create a parent controller, assign the utility service to your scope and then every child controller will inherit this without you having to include it.

Example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/NI7V9cLkQmEtWO36CPXy?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Utils) {
    $scope.utils = Utils;
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, Utils) {
   $scope.undefined1 = Utils.isUndefinedOrNull(1);  // standard DI
   $scope.undefined2 = $scope.utils.isUndefinedOrNull(1);  // MainCtrl is parent

});

app.factory('Utils', function() {
  var service = {
     isUndefinedOrNull: function(obj) {
         return !angular.isDefined(obj) || obj===null;
     }

  }

  return service;
});
```

Or you could add it to the rootScope as well.  Just a few options for extending angular with your own utility functions.

Comment: I strongly believe that utility functions shouldn't be DI

Comment: @slo2ols to encapsulate it you might create a service and inject it only to the roo

Answer (score 14):

[I asked the same question of the lodash maintainers a while back](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/306) and they replied by mentioning the `!=` operator can be used here:

```
if(newVal != null) {
  // newVal is defined
}
```

This uses JavaScript's type coercion to check the value for `undefined` or `null`.

If you are using JSHint to lint your code, add the following comment blocks to tell it that you know what you are doing - most of the time `!=` is considered bad.

```
/* jshint -W116 */ 
if(newVal != null) {
/* jshint +W116 */
  // newVal is defined
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not simply use `angular.isObject` with negation? e.g.

```
if (!angular.isObject(obj)) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: ... but is a great option if you do know what type the value is and can choose an `angular.isX` method to match.

Comment: `null` is an object

Comment: From the `isObject` doc: Returns: True if `value` is an `Object` but not `null`.

Answer (score 7):

@STEVER's answer is satisfactory.  However, I thought it may be useful to post a slightly different approach.  I use a method called isValue which returns true for all values except null, undefined, NaN, and Infinity.  Lumping in NaN with null and undefined is the real benefit of the function for me.  Lumping Infinity in with null and undefined is more debatable, but frankly not that interesting for my code because I practically never use Infinity.

The following code is inspired by [Y.Lang.isValue](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Lang.html#method_isValue).  Here is the [source](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/yui_js_yui-lang.js.html#l214) for Y.Lang.isValue.

```
/**
 * A convenience method for detecting a legitimate non-null value.
 * Returns false for null/undefined/NaN/Infinity, true for other values,
 * including 0/false/''
 * @method isValue
 * @static
 * @param o The item to test.
 * @return {boolean} true if it is not null/undefined/NaN || false.
 */
angular.isValue = function(val) {
  return !(val === null || !angular.isDefined(val) || (angular.isNumber(val) && !isFinite(val)));
};
```

Or as part of a factory

```
.factory('lang', function () {
  return {
    /**
     * A convenience method for detecting a legitimate non-null value.
     * Returns false for null/undefined/NaN/Infinity, true for other values,
     * including 0/false/''
     * @method isValue
     * @static
     * @param o The item to test.
     * @return {boolean} true if it is not null/undefined/NaN || false.
     */
    isValue: function(val) {
      return !(val === null || !angular.isDefined(val) || (angular.isNumber(val) && !isFinite(val)));
  };
})
```

Comment: Why not replace `val === null || !angular.isDefined(val)` with just `val == null` ?

Answer (score 3):

[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil) provides a shorthand method to check if undefined or null:
`_.isNil(yourVariable)`