# "isNull" in AngulaJS with a non defind value

Tags: angularjs, zero

In angular JS I use the "isNull" function, the problem is that the value I put in it is not null but not defined. How can you make it behave as if the undefined value were null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined or null for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910192/undefined-or-null-for-angularjs)

Comment: What is the isNull function ? AngularJS API doesn't provide it

Comment: OP was probably referring to [`angular.isDefined`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined), or the converse [`angular.isUndefined`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined). You really don't need these crufty functions. `value != null` (note the loose inequality) is sufficient to test for both `null` and `undefined`.