# Why do I have to use the window. prefix here?

Tags: javascript, module, scope, global

Why on earth does this work:

```
FOO = window.FOO || {isFoo: true};
```

But this doesn't:

```
FOO = FOO || {isFoo: true};
```

Since FOO and window.FOO both reference the same thing (both are running in the global scope).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `FOO` is not declared, but `window` is. Trying to access an undeclared variable will throw a `ReferenceError`, but accessing an undefined property will not.

You can get around it by using `typeof`:

```
FOO = typeof FOO != 'undefined' ? FOO : {isFoo: true};
```