# Javascript wait until last event fired in callback before proceeding

Tags: javascript, setinterval

This is pretty much a basic Javascript question even though it involves some Chrome Extension API.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        //complete may fire multiple times per page update
        var timer = 0, interval;
        console.log(changeInfo.status);
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (timer == 5) {
                console.log('here');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            timer++;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

I think all my script does right now is delay everything.  What I want it to do is every time a 'complete' status happens, I want to check for 5 seconds to go by and then log 'here'.  If another 'complete' fires, I want to get rid of the previous timer and start a new one.  Basically wait until all 'complete's are fired...I need help fixing my interval logic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your `timer`, and `interval` outside the function scope, or it'll declare a new one in that scope, and your clearInterval can't clear previous interval callback.

Edit: Thanks to  [stdob--](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob), now changed the variable outside to stick to the eventTarget, so no need to declare `variables` before register event anymore.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        //complete may fire multiple times per page update
        console.log(changeInfo.status);
        // Clear prev counter, if exist.
        if (this.interval != null) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        // init timer
        this.timer = 0;                
        this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (this.timer == 5) {
                console.log('here');
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                this.interval = null;
            }
            this.timer++;
        }.bind(this), 1000);  // Important to .bind(this) so that context will remain consistent.
    }
});
```

So now every `interval` and `timer` points to the same target.

Or if you doesn't care about what happens in every second, why not use `setTimeout`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        console.log(changeInfo.status);
        if (this.timeout != null) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }

        this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("here");
            this.timeout = null;
        }.bind(this), 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Best way use static variable: this.interval = setInterval(...)

Comment: @stdob but then if he use the setInterval way, he needs to bind the interval callback to `this`, right?

Comment: Why not if he not want access to interval outise? Some like this: 
`if (typeof this.interval == 'undefined') this.interval = null;` @fuyushimoya

Comment: @stdob-- yep, I take a cheat here use `if (this.interval != null)` to check if it exist, take a look to check if I made some mistake?

Comment: It would be more accurate to check by `typeof` if variable is declared or not. And can be set to `null`: `clearInterval` fully accepts null as input. @fuyushimoya

Comment: @stdob-- I get that from [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript), and [jquery-Equality](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#equality), so I think `this.interval != null` should be enough?

Comment: Of course - it's work. But this conceptual question - what if you want to assign a value different from `null` in the first function call? )) @fuyushimoya

Comment: To be quite boring, the best option would be: `if (!this.hasOwnProperty("interval")) this.interval = null;` @fuyushimoya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82424/discussion-between-fuyushimoya-and-stdob).