# How to check null and undefined both values for the property?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two properties where i need to check null and undefined both for each, how can i use that in if else statements ?

main.js

```
   var validateControlRating = function () {
            if ( ($scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey === null || 
                $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey === undefined)
                &&
               ($scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey === null ||
                $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey === undefined) ) {
              $scope.caculatedRatingDiv = false;
            } else {
            $http.get('app/control/rest/calculateControlEffectiveness/' + $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey + '/' + $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey).success(function (data) {
                $scope.calcaulatedRating = data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.statusClass ='status invalid userErrorInfo';
                var errorMessage = error.data.errorMsg;
                if (error.data.techErrorMsg) {
                    errorMessage = error.data.techErrorMsg;
                }
                $scope.statusInfo = errorMessage;
             });
            $scope.ratingValidationMsg = '';
            $scope.ratingWinValidationClass = 'valid';
            $scope.caculatedRatingDiv = true;
            $scope.enableRatingSave = false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: if (!$scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey && !$scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey) {

Comment: You can also use not operator as above, or like @adeneo's answer, both should work.

Comment: I've also stored the value in a variable in these situations, if the length of those values is a concern. 
if (perfKey === null || perfKey === undefined), etc.

Comment: @AhmetCetin not operator is not checking for null

Comment: sure it does, check here: https://jsbin.com/yubizakebe/edit?js,console

Comment: if you experience problem, maybe you have problem somewhere else, or typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tedious in javascript, you have to write each condition, and use parentheses etc

```
if ( ($scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey === null || 
      $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey === undefined)
      &&
     ($scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey === null ||
      $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey === undefined) ) {...
```

---

or just

```
if ([null, undefined].indexOf( $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey ) === -1
    &&
    [null, undefined].indexOf( $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey ) === -1) {...
```

Comment: its not checking for null and executing else condition

Comment: i edited my question and added according to your answer its still thrwing error i am not sure where my code is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to to check this correclty, check for `undefined` then for `null`
and use `&&` not `||` because your code will go to check null value for undefined variable and this surely will throw exception
**code:**

```
if( typeof myVar == 'undefined' ? false: myVar )
{    // go here defined and value not null  

}
```

or 
**code:**

```
if(typeof myVar != 'undefined' && myVar)
{    // go here defined and value not null  

}
```

In your code check will go like

```
if ((typeof $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey !== undefined||
     typeof $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey !== undefined) &&
    ($scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey !== null ||
      $scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey !== null)) {
    //  do home work
}else {  // do other home work  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negate operator as well, but this would make work for "false" as well:

```
if (!$scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlPerformanceRatingKey && !$scope.controlProcessRatingDTO.controlDesignRatingKey) {
```

This is a bit shorter but if you want to treat False values separately, then use the Adeneo's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if ( some_variable == null ){
  // some_variable is either null or undefined
}
```

taken from: [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript)