# [].sort ignoring undefined values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array containing undefined/null and numbers, so that undefined/null values always come first:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a == undefined) return -1;
    if (b == undefined) return  1;
    return a - b;
}
```

However, when the array contains an undefined value it becomes the last element

```
[-1, 0, 1, undefined, 2, 3].sort(sorter);     // [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, undefined]
```

while it gets sorted correctly if the value is null

```
[-1, 0, 1, null, 2, 3].sort(sorter);          // [null, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this result in exactly the same order since null == undefined?

Comment: They are not the same... The answer from mar10 clears it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `console.log(a, b)` to your `sorter` function, you'll see that the `undefined` value is never passed into the `sorter` function. I think that the interpreter thinks the it's a "gap" in the array and thus don't really consider it as a value.

And by the way, `null == undefined` is `true`, but `null === undefined` is false, they are not the same thing.