# How to conditionally add a view in React | React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am rendering rows of two items in a React Native flatlets. Usually there are two but sometimes there are only one item in the row because not everything is an even number of things.

```
  var row = new Object();
  row.left = card1;
  if (card2 != null);
  row.right = card2;
  rows[] is an array of row which is two items.
```

// so I have a row of two items but one of them might be null. If it's null I want to put in the placeholder instead.

// item is really a row of two elements. So item.left and item.right is generally not null but sometimes if uneven item.right will be null or undefined.

```
renderFlatListItem(item) {
  return (
    <View>
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.onButtonPress(item.left)}>
    <View>
    <Card  <!-- Card is from react-native-elements TouchableHighlight does not accept it so I wrapped it in View-->
         title={item.left.text+''}
         image={{uri: item.left.imageUrl}}>
    </Card>
    </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
<!--  $$$$$ I want to be able to switch this one out dynamically depending on if item.right is undefined or not -->
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.onButtonPress(item.right)}>        
    <Card
         title={item.right == 'undefined' : 'undefined' item.right.text+''}
         image={{uri: item.right.imageUrl}}>
    </Card>
    </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>

  );
```

}

So I might be able to always leave the right TouchableHighlight in the layout but at the least I need to be able to point to blank imageURL in case it's null.  So how do I conditionally change the imageURL and secondly how could I swap out the whole TouchableHighlight view with some other View  if row.right is null or undefined?
I saw: [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript)
About checking null, but I am dereferencing twice. item.right.text so not sure if I can just say

```
item.right.text || 'Not Available'
```

What if item.right is null?

And the other thing was what if I want to swap in another view like one that is not highlightable conditionally if item.right is null or undefined. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

For conditional render, use the following snippet:

```
{item.right ? <TouchableHighlight /> : null}
```

For showing image, if item.right is available, try:

```
image={{ uri: item.right && item.right.imageUrl }}
```

Comment: Ok and if I wanted to put something else it in it's place?  {item.right ? <TouchableHighlight> </TouchableHighlight> : <View> <Button/> </View> } is correct syntax?  Do I need to put inside brackets or anything?

Comment: how about returning a different URL if item.right is false?

Comment: I am not convinced that item.right will be ok if item.right is undefined

Comment: Yes for first comment - no need to put brackets. But putting brackets won't hurt. If item is undefined, it won't work. `item && item.right && item.right.imageUrl` will work. Use the ternary operator for giving alternate url. `item.right ? item.right.imageUrl : alternateUrl`