# how to check if variable value is undefined or ''undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created REST API using node.js.since the API consumer is not correctly populating the object & some of the object attributes are coming `"undefined"` and sometimes `undefined`.

I have added a request interceptor that rejects API request if the required request parameters are missing

this is how my code looks like today. I just want to check if there is any better way to handle it.

```
(!variable_name || variable_name === 'undefined')
```

Comment: Your title says _"&"_ but your question says _"or"_; which is it?

Comment: Why would you set a variable to `'undefined'` instead of `undefined`

Comment: can you be more specific, `!variable` means it could be 0, empty string, undefined, null (and I'm probably forgetting others). you can check for exact equality to undefined by saying `foo === undefined`. note the three equals. the string 'undefined' is just a word, you may as well have said 'bar' there.

Comment: Your JavaScript isn't a valid expression

Comment: also you probably mean `||` instead of `!!`

Comment: `I am doing like` and getting a syntax error in the console no doubt

Comment: sorry for the typo, its ||.

Comment: I have created REST API in using node.js.  I can see for some reason the variable is coming 'undefined' & for some cases undefined.

Comment: I will prefer !foo insted of foo === undefined. wondering if (!foo || foo === 'undefined') can be shorten as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: I've only ever got this to work: `if (typeof variable_name === "undefined")`.

Comment: @I.R.R. you only need if your variable might not exist. Like testing for `window` in an unknown context. If you _know_ you have a variable available, `typeof` is not necessary.

Comment: Oh that explains a lot, since most of the time I'm working with data that may or may not be there.

Comment: "*the API consumer is not correctly ..."* Fix this then.

Answer (score 2):

The most specific and self-explaining way is:

```
foo === undefined || foo === 'undefined'
```

While

```
!foo || foo === 'undefined'
```

condition is equivalent to

```
foo === undefined || foo === null || foo === false ||  foo === '' ||  foo === 0 || foo === NaN || foo === 'undefined'
```

This may result in false positive for any listed falsy value. If this is the case, `!foo` shouldn't be used.

A shorter way is to coerce `foo` to a string:

```
'' + foo === 'undefined'
```

This may result in false positive for any object that has `toString()` returning `undefined`. If this is undesirable, it shouldn't be used.

*This is a workaround to fix a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. `undefined` shouldn't be indistinguishable from `'undefined'` string because this way there's no way to tell if it was originally `'undefined'` string ('undefined' is a word) or `undefined` that was accidentally stringified.*

Comment: The most self-explaining way is to avoid this situation altogether and treat  `"undefined"` as it is => a string.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not sure what you mean. OP clearly stated that a value can be either `undefined` or `'undefined'` string because it was supplied by API this way. I agree that the distinction between those two just complicates everything at this point.

Comment: And that's this API that needs to be fixed. Adding chewing-gum everywhere to avoid leaks will just make your fingers sticky.

Comment: @Kaiido Also, depending on the meaning of this value, 'undefined' string may be totally unacceptable because it could be originally a string with this value and there's no way to distinguish it from `'undefined'` string that was erroneously created.

Comment: Indeed. That just goes my way. (ps: I think your answer is good at answering this bad question, but a small note about **you're doing it wrong™** might be a bonus.

Comment: @Kaiido I can easily imagine that the OP has no other choice with faulty API. But I added a clarification for future readers.