# How to check undefined object properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, conditional-statements

i have to push the drug if either price is there in the object, I wanted to check if object is not undefined/null , does it make sense to these conditions ?

issue is its adding mailPrice when it is coming as `{}` , any idea ?

main.js

```
 _.forEach(drugs, function (drug) {
    if ((drug.retailPrice !== undefined && drugPrice.retailPrice !== null)  || (drug.mailPrice !== undefined && drug.mailPrice !== null)) {
          response.push(drug);
        }
});
```

Comment: what is your question ? are you facing any problem with it ? whether it makes sense or not depend how are the values are being used

Comment: @CodeManiac updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an object is empty using `Object.keys`:

```
const isEmpty = obj => Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
```

Now you should be able to do:

```
if (!isEmpty(drug)) {
  response.push(drug);
}
```