# Why is boolean true in firestore query (typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, boolean

I am querying Firestore in Angular 8, using AngularFire. When I query a string (e.g. `module_version` in code below) it works, but trying to query a boolean field in Firestore doesn't work properly with my code below. I can only get all objects with `active==true`, but not `false`. When I hover the boolean variable `active` inside the query (in VSCode) it says "var active: true", instead of "var active: boolean" as I would have expected. I am guessing this is the problem, as I can query `true`, but not `false`. Hovering the string variable `module_version` gives "var module_version: string". (I have read answers to questions about true/false in Javascript, but didn't get any the wiser from this.)

Why does my variable seem to automatically get set to `true` and what can I do about it?

```
constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
 this.activeFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
 this.module_versionFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  this.modules$ = combineLatest(
    this.activeFilter$,
    this.module_versionFilter$
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(([active, module_version]) => 
    afs.collection<Module>('Modules', ref => {
      let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      if (active) { query = query.where('active', '==', active) };
      if (module_version) { query = query.where('module_version', '==', module_version) };
      return query;
    }).valueChanges()
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  Won't the `active` where clause only be added to the query if `active` is `true`?  (because it is inside the `if (active)` block?)

Comment: No, you are of course right! Thanks! I was thinking it would be added if the `active` variable exists, similarly to `module_version`. But I guess I would have to do `if (active != null)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an undefined or null variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559318/how-to-check-for-an-undefined-or-null-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in the comment thread.  As discussed, your problem is that:

```
if (active)
```

Will only be true if `active` itself is true.  So the query is only added when `active` is true.

You want something more like:

```
if (typeof(active) !== 'undefined' && active !== null)
```