# check the data of ckeditor is null or not

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I'm using the ckeditor 3.4 as text editor for my website, and want to validate the data at client side first, before submitting the data to server.

I can get the data of editor by using this code: 
var editorData = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

but having trouble to validate data. The problem is: 
- The data should be invalid if user didn't enter anything into editor or enter only some space or line break (null data)

by default, CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData() return `<br />` if user didn't type anything and return

```
<p>
 &nbsp;</p>
<br />
```

if user enter a line break (may be many `<p>&nbsp;</p>` if user enter many line break)

please help me to check this case should be invalid (null data) both at client side (js - jquery 1.4.2) and server side (php 5)?

thanks

Comment: The best way to determine an 'empty' input in terms of it containing no actual presentational data would likely be a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Specifically:

```
var str = $('<p> &nbsp;</p> <br />').text();
if(str.replace(/\s/g,"") == ""){
}
```

Comment: how to check this: '<p>
 &nbsp;</p>
<br />'

Comment: I have tried jquery validate plugin and it works. the problem now is