# How can I ignore two null or unassigned values in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, onblur, htmltext

I have this code to compare two values to verify they are identical:

```
$(document).on("blur", "[id$=boxSection5Total]", function (e) {
    var totalvalue = $(this).val();
    var paymenttotalvalue = $('[id$=boxPaymentAmount]').val();
    if (totalvalue != paymenttotalvalue) {
        console.log("The value in 'Total' does not equal the previous value in 'Payment Total.'");
        alert("The value in 'Total' does NOT equal the previous value in 'Payment Total.' payment total is " + paymenttotalvalue + " and total is " + totalvalue);
    }
    else {
        console.log("The value in 'Total' DOES equal the previous value in 'Payment Total'");
    }
});
```

However, if both text elements are left blank, it fails - they are considered to not be equal (the "if (totalvalue != paymenttotalvalue)" condition is true).

How can I refactor the code so that it ignores cases where both elements have been left blank?

Something like:

```
$(document).on("blur", "[id$=boxSection5Total]", function (e) {
    var totalvalue = $(this).val();
    var paymenttotalvalue = $('[id$=boxPaymentAmount]').val();
    if ((totalvalue == null) & (paymenttotalvalue == null)) {
        return;
    }
    . . .
});
```

?

Both "boxSection5Total" and "boxPaymentAmount" are text elements (textboxes).

Comment: The value will not be 'null' and `"" == null` is false. The simplest - and most idiomatic - change to the existing would be `if (!totalvalue && !paymenttotalvalue) { return; }`, but likely better to combine with the other conditional.

Comment: @up true, if it comes from html form its mostly considered as empty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check specifically on null you should try something like this.

```
if (totalvalue !== null && paymenttotalvalue !== null && totalvalue != paymenttotalvalue)
```

If you want to check for untruthy (also see here: [JavaScript: how to test if a variable is not NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361585/javascript-how-to-test-if-a-variable-is-not-null)) you can use this:

```
if (totalvalue && paymenttotalvalue && totalvalue != paymenttotalvalue)
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are in fact blank text values then use....

```
if(totalvalue === "" && paymenttotalvalue === "")
{
    return;
}
```

or (i think)

```
if(totalvalue == 1 && paymenttotalvalue == 1)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: and === instead of == (e.g., false == "" is actually true)

Comment: The getElementById won't work, because the Sharepoint elements have a bunch of greek, russian, bulgarian, etc. prepended to them, like "id=zorbaIvan_bulgarischesSemillaDe0143209870945634-boxSection5Total"

Comment: Return a boolean in an event handler?

Comment: @ B. Clay Shannon You can return what you want. The code I added was only supposed to be used as sudo code for the example.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge: Okay, no sweat.