# How to check if a value is not null and not empty string in JS

Tags: javascript

Is there any check if a value is not null and not empty string in Javascript? I'm using the following one:

```
var data; //get its value from db 
if(data != null && data != '') {
   // do something
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is another better solution. Thanks.

Comment: `if(data)` would suffice as it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361614/3512538)

Comment: I tried this but in one of the two cases it was not working.

Comment: thank you everybody, I will try this. I hope it will work.

Comment: `undefined` is one of the special cases which, according to your logic, should trigger `// do something` but won't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

If you truly want to confirm that a variable is not null and not an empty string specifically, you would write:

```
if(data !== null && data !== '') {
   // do something
}
```

Notice that I changed your code to check for type equality (`!==`|`===`).

If, however you just want to make sure, that a code will run only for "reasonable" values, then you can, as others have stated already, write:

```
if (data) {
  // do something
}
```

Since, in javascript, both null values, and empty strings, equals to false (i.e. `null == false`).

The difference between those 2 parts of code is that, for the first one, every value that is not specifically null or an empty string, will enter the `if`. But, on the second one, every true-ish value will enter the `if`: `false`, `0`, `null`, `undefined` and empty strings, would not.

Comment: 0 is a reasonable value in a lot of cases

Comment: that's why the word reasonable is wrapped with quotes :)

Comment: @Adam If it doesn't, you can just leave it empty and use an else. That'll always invert as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't this be data !== null || data !== '' instead of using && ?

Comment: @Imdad the OP asked to check if the value is not null AND not an empty string, so no.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of using

```
if(data !== null && data !== ''  && data!==undefined) {

// do something
}
```

You can use below simple code

```
if(Boolean(value)){ 
// do something 
}
```

- Values that are intuitively “empty”, like 0, an empty string, null, undefined, and NaN, become false
- Other values become true

Comment: I like this solution as it's the cleanest.

Answer (score 22):

Both `null` and an empty string are falsy values in JS. Therefore,

```
if (data) { ... }
```

is completely sufficient.

A note on the side though: I would avoid having a variable in my code that could manifest in different types. If the data will eventually be a string, then I would initially define my variable with an empty string, so you can do this:

```
if (data !== '') { ... }
```

without the null (or any weird stuff like `data = "0"`) getting in the way.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (data?.trim().length > 0) {
   //use data
}
```

the `?.` [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will short-circuit and return `undefined` if data is `nullish` (`null` or `undefined`) which will evaluate to false in the `if` expression.

Comment: I honestly did not know about this operator..

unfortunately a few Android browsers don't support it, but otherwise support is pretty good!

Comment: Be careful with nullables, depending on your JavaScript version

Comment: @Nando not just "your" version but your target audience too, but ideally you'd be using babel to transpile out any syntax that is too new for your user's browsers.

Answer (score 7):

I often test for truthy value and also for empty spaces in the string:

```
if(!(!data || data.trim().length === 0)) {
  // do something here
}
```

If you have a string consisting of one or more empty spaces it will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution to check if string is `undefined` or `null` or `""`:-

```
const value = null;
if(!value) {
  console.log('value is either null, undefined or empty string');
}
```

Comment: Be careful, this will also trigger if the value is falsy: `0`, `false`

Answer (score 2):

Both null and empty could be validated as follows:

```
<script>
function getName(){
    var myname = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    if(myname != '' && myname != null){
        alert("My name is "+myname);
    }else{
        alert("Please Enter Your Name");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try it**----------

```js
function myFun(){
var inputVal=document.getElementById("inputId").value;
if(inputVal){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<span style='color:green'>The value is "+inputVal+'</span>';
}
else{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Something error happen! the input May be empty.</span>";
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId">
<input type="button" onclick="myFun()" value="View Result">
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got so fed up with checking for null and empty strings specifically, that I now usually just write and call a small function to do it for me.

```
/**
 * Test if the given value equals null or the empty string.
 * 
 * @param {string} value
**/
const isEmpty = (value) => value === null || value === '';

// Test:
isEmpty('');        // true
isEmpty(null);      // true
isEmpty(1);         // false
isEmpty(0);         // false
isEmpty(undefined); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

When we code empty in essence could mean any one of the following given the circumstances;

- 0 as in number value
- 0.0 as in float value
- '0' as in string value
- '0.0' as in string value
- null as in Null value, as per chance it could also capture  undefined or it may not
- undefined as in undefined value
- false as in false truthy value, as per chance 0 also as truthy but what if we want to capture false as it is
- '' empty sting value with no white space or tab
- '        ' string with white space or tab only

In real life situation as OP stated we may wish to test them all or at times we may only wish to test for limited set of conditions.

Generally `if(!a){return true;}` serves its purpose most of the time however it will not cover wider set of conditions.

Another hack that has made its round is `return (!value || value == undefined || value == "" || value.length == 0);`

But what if we need control on whole process?

There is no simple whiplash solution in native core JavaScript it has to be adopted. Considering we drop support for legacy IE11 (to be honest even windows has so should we) below solution born out of frustration works in all modern browsers;

```
 function empty (a,b=[])
 {if(!Array.isArray(b)) return; 
 var conditions=[null,'0','0.0',false,undefined,''].filter(x => !b.includes(x));
 if(conditions.includes(a)|| (typeof a === 'string' && conditions.includes(a.toString().trim())))
 {return true;};
 return false;};`
```

Logic behind the solution is function has two parameters **a** and **b**, a is value we need to check, b is a array with set conditions we need to exclude from predefined conditions as listed above. Default value of b is set to an empty array [].

First run of function is to check if b is an array or not, if not then early exit the function.

next step is to compute array difference from `[null,'0','0.0',false,undefined,'']` and from array b. if b is an empty array predefined conditions will stand else it will remove matching values.

conditions = [predefined set] - [to be excluded set]
**filter** function does exactly that make use of it.
Now that we have conditions in array set all we need to do is check if value is in conditions array.
**includes** function does exactly that no need to write nasty loops of your own let JS engine do the heavy lifting.

**Gotcha**
if we are to convert a into string for comparison then 0 and 0.0 would run fine however Null and Undefined would through error blocking whole script. We need edge case solution. Below simple **||** covers the edge case if first condition is not satisfied. Running another early check through include makes early exit if not met.

```
if(conditions.includes(a)||  (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof a) && conditions.includes(a.toString().trim())))
```

trim() function will cover for wider white spaces and tabs only value and will only come into play in edge case scenario.

**Play ground**

```js
function empty (a,b=[]){
if(!Array.isArray(b)) return;
conditions=[null,'0','0.0',false,undefined,''].filter(x => !b.includes(x));
if(conditions.includes(a)|| 
(['string', 'number'].includes(typeof a) && conditions.includes(a.toString().trim()))){
 return true;
} 
return false;
}

console.log('1 '+empty());
console.log('2 '+empty(''));
console.log('3 '+empty('      '));
console.log('4 '+empty(0));
console.log('5 '+empty('0'));
console.log('6 '+empty(0.0));
console.log('7 '+empty('0.0'));
console.log('8 '+empty(false));
console.log('9 '+empty(null));
console.log('10 '+empty(null,[null]));
console.log('11 dont check 0 as number '+empty(0,['0']));
console.log('12 dont check 0 as string '+empty('0',['0']));
console.log('13 as number for false as value'+empty(false,[false]));
```

Lets make it complex - what if our value to compare is array its self and can be as deeply nested it can be. what if we are to check if any value in array is empty, it can be an edge business case.

```js
function empty (a,b=[]){
    if(!Array.isArray(b)) return;

    conditions=[null,'0','0.0',false,undefined,''].filter(x => !b.includes(x));
    if(Array.isArray(a) && a.length > 0){
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { if (empty(a[i],b))return true;} 
    } 
    
    if(conditions.includes(a)|| 
    (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof a) && conditions.includes(a.toString().trim()))){
     return true;
    } 
    return false;
    }

console.log('checking for all values '+empty([1,[0]]));
console.log('excluding for 0 from condition '+empty([1,[0]], ['0']));
```

it simple and wider use case function that I have adopted in my framework;

- Gives control over as to what exactly is the definition of empty in a given situation
- Gives control over to redefine conditions of empty
- Can compare for almost for every thing from string, number, float, truthy, null, undefined and deep arrays
- Solution is drawn keeping in mind the resuability and flexibility. All other answers are suited in case if simple one or two cases are to be dealt with. However, there is always a case when definition of empty changes while coding above snippets make work flawlessly in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateAttrs(arg1, arg2, arg3,arg4){
    var args = Object.values(arguments);
    return (args.filter(x=> x===null || !x)).length<=0
}
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, null));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',undefined, 3, 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, '', 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, null));
```