# How to check the variable is not null , not empty but zero should pass in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to check number is non null , non empty.

But it should pass numerics like 0 1 2 etc.

```
var xxx=0;
if(xxx){
// for 0 not coming here
}else{
// All empty,undefined,'' should go here  --- 
}
```

Comment: What is "empty" and why is it different than undefined?

Comment: `if (isFinite(xxx))`

Comment: `0` is considered as `false` in a Javascript condition

Comment: Can't you just use `if (typeof x === "number") { ... }`?

Comment: Referred question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361585/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-not-null is similar, but this has a value by itself

Comment: Standard Number.isInteger or Number.isFinite can be used

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check for truthy or for zero value.

```
if (x || x === 0){
    // 0, 1, 2, 3
} else {
    // null, undefined, ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```js
function is_number(val){
if (val || val === 0){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}

}
console.log(is_number(0))
console.log(is_number(1))
console.log(is_number(null))
console.log(is_number(""))
```

Comment: Standard Number.IsInteger or Number.isFinite  may be sufficient