# Error on inequality value in blade template Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm currently using javascript code on my blade.php (Laravel) page and I have a strange error: My != is not accepted:

```
if({{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} != null) {
    if (newQty > {{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }}) {
        $('input[name="quantity"]').val({{ $CurrentProduct -> disposable_quantity }});
    }
}
```

If I put a == my code no longer contains errors. I don't understand

Comment: check browser logs... and share it here .... what are logs... this is not fully cleared

Comment: Checking for not null in JS can be weird you may need !== https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361585/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-not-null

Comment: I only have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!=' @GauravBhardwaj

Comment: What's the output of `{{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }}`?

Comment: null or an int @MoshFeu

Comment: Replace `!=` to `!==`

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick, then you could leave out the null altogether and negate the variable,

if ( !{{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} ) {...}

Comment: Seems like there is a case which `{{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }}` render nothing so the `if` statement looks something like `if (== null)` which throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=='`

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to confirm that a variable is not `null` and not an `empty string` specifically, you would write :

```
if({{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} !== null) {
   // do something
}
```

I changed your code to check for type equality (`!==`|`===`).
You can also use below simple code :

```
if(Boolean({{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} )){ 
  // do something 
}
```

Note : Values that are intuitively `empty`, like `0`, an `empty string`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`, become **false** 
Other values become **true**

Comment: Is casting to Boolean really necessary?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm that's an alternative. There are a lot of alternative way like `if (data) {
  // do something
}`