# How to check date is not zero in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to check if date is not equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. How can I check it in javascript?

I checked with `date !== null` but it is not working.

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a variable is not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361585/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-not-null)

Comment: No. It is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check "0000-00-00 00:00:00" with

```
Date.parse(date) // NaN
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 2):

Having `0000-00-00 00:00:00` suggest that you not deal with `Date` object in JS but string comparing it in `if` statement should do:

```
if (data !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') { ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you use `date !=== 0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: I used it but checking if there is better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using ternary operators:

```
(date === '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse );
```

Also, below is an example using indexOf. - There are definitely a few ways to do this but not exactly sure what you're looking for with your use-case.

```js
const zeroDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
const realDate = '2020-10-13 00:04:05';

//check to see if indexOf '0000-00-00' exists in zeroDate string
// if true then log 'yes', if false then log 'no'
// this will log 'yes' since '0000-00-00' exists
(zeroDate.indexOf('0000-00-00') == 0  ? console.log('yes') : console.log('no') );


//same as above but for realDate string
//since there is no occurance of '0000-00-00' it will log 'no'
(realDate.indexOf('0000-00-00') == 0  ? console.log('yes') : console.log('no') );
```