# Remove ALL white spaces from text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#topNav" + $("#breadCrumb2nd").text().replace(" ", "")).addClass("current");
```

This is a snippet from my code. I want to add a class to an ID after getting another ID's text property. The problem with this, is the ID holding the text I need, contains gaps between the letters.

I would like the white spaces removed. I have tried `TRIM()`and `REPLACE()` but this only partially works. The `REPLACE()` only removes the 1st space.

Answer (score 1824, accepted):

You have to tell replace() to repeat the regex:

```
.replace(/ /g,'')
```

The **g** character makes it a "global" match, meaning it repeats the search through the entire string.  Read about this, and other RegEx modifiers available in JavaScript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

If you want to match all whitespace, and not just the literal space character, use `\s` instead:

```
.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

You can also use [`.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) if you're using a sufficiently recent version of JavaScript, but there's not really any reason to for your specific use case, since catching *all* whitespace requires a regex, and when using a regex with `.replaceAll`, it must be global, so you just end up with extra typing:

```
.replaceAll(/\s/g,'')
```

Comment: Coffeescript will complain about that regex for some god awful reason. Instead I had to go ahead and using `.replace(/\s+/g, '')` which is totally fine by me.

Answer (score 363):

```
.replace(/\s+/, "")
```

Will replace the **first whitespace only**, this includes spaces, tabs and new lines.

To replace all whitespace in the string you need to use global mode

```
.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

Answer (score 33):

Now you can use "replaceAll":

```
console.log(' a b    c d e   f g   '.replaceAll(' ',''));
```

will print:

```
abcdefg
```

But not working in every possible browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: I've also noticed that the `replaceAll` method runs almost twice as fast as the regex solutions. Not that it really matters much unless you're dealing with extremely large volumes, but just nice to know.

Comment: The solution looks simpler and may be faster in execution time, but it only removes spaces. If you need to remove other types of whitespace, that are not part of the original question (e.g. tab or new line) that may occur when copying/pasting, you need to use one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 22):

Regex for remove white space

```
\s+
```

```js
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

or

```
[ ]+
```

```js
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace(/[ ]+/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

Remove all white space at begin of string

```
^[ ]+
```

```js
var str = "    Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace(/^[ ]+/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

remove all white space at end of string

```
[ ]+$
```

```js
var str = "Visit Microsoft!      ";
var res = str.replace(/[ ]+$/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

```
    var mystring="fg gg";
   console.log(mystring.replaceAll(' ',''))
```

Answer (score 10):

**** 100% working**

use `replace(/ +/g,'_')`:

```js
let text = "I     love you"
text = text.replace( / +/g, '_') // replace with underscore ('_')

console.log(text) // I_love_you
```

Answer (score 8):

Using [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regex, as mentioned in the other answers, is certainly the best solution.

But, just for fun, you can also remove all whitespaces from a text by using [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`String.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const text = ' a b    c d e   f g   ';
const newText = text.split(/\s/).join('');

console.log(newText); // prints abcdefg
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand why we need to use regex here when we can simply use `replaceAll`

```
let result = string.replaceAll(' ', '')
```

`result` will store `string` without spaces

Comment: FWIW I had to switch to regex as some 'jest' ran my tests in a node env which didnt support this

Comment: This comment deserves more upvotes! Regex for repeated space replacement is like shooting a mosquito with a gun, it is much slower and definitely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
let str = 'a big fat hen clock mouse '
console.log(str.split(' ').join(''))
// abigfathenclockmouse
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.replace(/\s/g,'')`

This will solve the problem.

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

simple solution could be : just replace white space ask key value

```
val = val.replace('&#160;', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can also use that `[^A-Za-z]` with `g` flag for removing all the spaces in text. Where `negated or complemente` or **^**. Show to the every character or range of character which is inside the brackets. And the about `g` is indicating that we search globally.

```js
let str = "D  S@ D2m4a   r k  23";

// We are only allowed the character in that range A-Za-z

str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,"");  // output:- DSDmark

console.log(str)
```

javascript - Remove ALL white spaces from text - Stack Overflow

Answer (score -2):

Use `replace(/\s+/g,'')`,

for example:

```
const stripped = '    My String With A    Lot Whitespace  '.replace(/\s+/g, '')// 'MyStringWithALotWhitespace'
```

Answer (score -3):

Using .replace(/\s+/g,'') works fine;

Example:

```
this.slug = removeAccent(this.slug).replace(/\s+/g,'');
```