# Removing all spaces from angular js ng-repeat variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one of my angular application I will get the values when I pass the key in ng-repeat.

Here each **rows** in **rowsdata** has values like `'my file1 data', 'my file2 data', 'my file3 data'`

But I need to pass it as `'myfile1data', 'myfile2data', 'myfile3data'`

When I used rows.replace(' ','') it is removing only the first space like `'myfile1 data', 'myfile2 data', 'myfile3 data'`

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas"> 
  <td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{data[rows.replace(' ','')]}}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**

But when I use

```
<td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{data[rows.replace(/ /g,'')]}}</td>
```

I got

```
Error: a is not a function OPERATORS["/"]@http://loclhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/a‌​ngular.js:5959 OPERATORS["/"]@http://loclhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/a‌​ngular.js:5959 binaryFn/<@http://loclhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/angul‌​ar.js:6292
```

Can anyone show me some solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)

Comment: how come duplicate....here i'm using the replace in html angular ng-repeat......not in the script.........

Comment: Why you are even using an MVC framework if you insist putting the business logic in your templates? Your controller is supposed to handle it, and that's the reason why it's not working.

Comment: because i'm using the same value with space in table title........

Comment: If and only if `rows` will **always** hold values having exactly 2 spaces or less - which isn't quite reliable - then you could use something not elegant at all (and neither recommended): `{{data[rows.replace(' ','').replace(' ', '')]}}`. Where, first `replace` will remove first space, second will remove second space... But as @Paolo Moretti suggested, your controller should manage this kind of work. Why can't you keep a list of keys without spaces inside your controller and use that as key mappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rows.replace(/ /g,'')
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas"> 
    <td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{rows.replace(/ /g,'')}}</td>
</tr>
```

Rows should already be the list item. For details of replace check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript); it has actually nothing to do with angular.

Comment: when i use `<td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{data[rows.replace(/ /g,'')]}}</td>` i got `Error: a is not a function OPERATORS["/"]@http://localhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:5959 OPERATORS["/"]@http://localhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:5959 binaryFn/<@http://localhost/jcp_standardwork/secure/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:6292`

Comment: It is hard to give any futher advice at the moment. Maybe you want to provide a JSFiddle, to get further help.

Comment: I don't think Angular will interpolate regex, you would need to write a custom directive instead

Answer (score 6):

The cleanest way to do so, that I've found, is to create a filter:

```
angular.module('moduleFilters', []).filter('classy', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return String(text).replace(/\s*/mg, "-");
  };
});
```

I've called mine classy, as in my use case, it's to make variables valid for classes. Let's call yours `compress` as we're compressing out spaces.

Then in your html just call

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas"> 
    <td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{rows|compress}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now you can call the `compress` filter from anywhere you import that filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas"> 
  <td ng-repeat="rows in rowdatas">{{data[rows.split(' ').join('')]}}</td>
</tr>
```

This works for me!